# Cross-browser window resize event - JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, resize

What is the correct (modern) method for tapping into the window resize event that works in Firefox, [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit), and Internet Explorer?

And can you turn both scrollbars on/off?

Comment: I'm also looking into this.  I'd like to try to apply the solutions offered here, but I'm afraid I don't understand the syntax:

$(window).

Is that something specific to jquery?

Comment: Byff, yes, $(window) is a jQuery construct. window.onresize is the equivalent in raw JavaScript.

Comment: This demo may help anybody to test on all browsers http://jsfiddle.net/subodhghulaxe/bHQV5/2/

Comment: `window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818474/how-to-trigger-the-window-resize-event-in-javascript#18693617

Comment: On Opera on mobile it is triggered each time top bar (browser UI) is showing/hiding.

Answer (score 370, accepted):

jQuery has a [built-in method](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) for this:

```
$(window).resize(function () { /* do something */ });
```

For the sake of UI responsiveness, you might consider using a setTimeout to call your code only after some number of milliseconds, as shown in the following example, inspired by [this](http://snipplr.com/view/6284/jquery--window-on-resize-event/):

```
function doSomething() {
    alert("I'm done resizing for the moment");
};

var resizeTimer;
$(window).resize(function() {
    clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
    resizeTimer = setTimeout(doSomething, 100);
});
```

Comment: Why this event is not fired when window is expanded to full screen with button?

Comment: @Sly For me it works,in Safari, Chrome and Mozilla on Mac.
Which browser do you use?

Comment: @Sly: `$('.button').on({ click: function(){ /* your code */ $(window).trigger('resize') })`

Comment: Also of note is that if you call a named function just type the name, don't quote it or put parentheses if there are no arguments to pass to it.)

Comment: Elijah, this is JavaScript.  What you wrote is not correct (except for one specific case when you are constructing with new).

Comment: Considering most need the optimized version for UI responsiveness, it would be nice if jQuery added a second parameter, being a delay (in millis) which would automatically add the 'responsiveness' logic as proposed above.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18745301/895558) below if you don't want to use jQuery.

Comment: I had a issue in Firefox saying that $ is not defined when the resize event was fired. I've put my resize function inside a setTimeout and it worked now!

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this jQuery function "adds" a function call to the current list of functions that should be called on a window resize. It does not overwrite existing events that are currently scheduled on a window resize.

Answer (score 49):

```
$(window).bind('resize', function () { 

    alert('resize');

});
```

Comment: I prefer the bind approach, since the resize() method is actually actually a shortcut for the full bind approach, and I often find that there is usually more than one event handler I *should* be applying to an element.

Comment: @Mike - Not only that, but I'm guessing the resize method has no "unbind" method in the event you want to remove the listener.  "bind" is definitely the way to go!

Answer (score 44):

Here is the non-jQuery way of tapping into the resize event:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // do stuff here
});
```

It works on all modern browsers. It does **not** throttle anything for you. [Here is an example](http://codepen.io/jondlm/pen/doijJ) of it in action.

Comment: this solution wouldn't be working in IE.  Fixed version with support of IE dom:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6927637/addeventlistener-in-internet-explorer

Comment: > It does not throttle anything for you.

Could you please elaborate? What should/would it throttle? Does it relate to the event firing many times in a row?

Comment: @josinalvo generally when you're listening to an event that fires _a lot_ you'll want to [debounce (e.g. lodash)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) it so you don't cause a bottleneck in your program.

Answer (score 17):

Sorry to bring up an old thread, but if someone doesn't want to use jQuery you can use this:

```
function foo(){....};
window.onresize=foo;
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will clobber any existing handlers that may be bound to window.onresize. If your script has to live an an ecosystem with other scripts, you shouldn't assume your script is the only one to want to do something on window resize. If you can't use a framework such as jQuery, you should at least consider grabbing the existing window.onresize, and adding your handler to the end of it, rather than completely clobbering it.

Comment: @TomAuger *"you should at least consider grabbing the existing window.onresize, and adding your handler to the end of it"* - you probably meant the opposite, i.e. "to call existing handler at the end of your handler"? I would really like to see a javascript code that would add something to the end of already existing function :-)

Comment: I see your point, in a sense - your new onResize handler needs to wrap the existing onResize. However, it doesn't have to call the function you wanted to add to onResize until after it has called the original onResize handler. So you can still make sure your new onResize function executes after the original onResize function, which is probably better than the reverse.

Answer (score 8):

Since you are open to jQuery, [this plugin](http://andowebsit.es/blog/noteslog.com/post/how-to-fix-the-resize-event-in-ie/) seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 5):

Using jQuery 1.9.1 I just found out that, although technically identical)*, this did not work in IE10 (but in Firefox):

```js
// did not work in IE10
$(function() {
    $(window).resize(CmsContent.adjustSize);
});
```

while this worked in both browsers:

```js
// did work in IE10
$(function() {
    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        CmsContent.adjustSize();
    };
});
```

*Edit:*
)* Actually **not** technically identical, as noted and explained in the comments by [WraithKenny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387233/wraithkenny) and [Henry Blyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3150057/henry-blyth).

Comment: There's two changes. Which one had the effect? (`.resize()` to `.bind('resize')` or adding the anonymous function? I'm thinking it's the second.)

Comment: @WraithKenny Good point. It very well may be that adding the anonymous function was what made it work. I don't recall if I tried it.

Comment: In the first case, the `adjustSize` method loses its context of `this`, whereas the second call `CmsContent.adjustSize()` preserves `this`, i.e. `this === CmsContent`. If the `CmsContent` instance is required in the `adjustSize` method, then the first case will fail. Second case will work for every kind of function call, so it's recommended to always pass an anonymous function.

Comment: @HenryBlyth Thank you! +1

Answer (score 4):

`jQuery` provides `$(window).resize()` function by default:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// function for resize of div/span elements
var $window = $( window ),
    $rightPanelData = $( '.rightPanelData' )
    $leftPanelData = $( '.leftPanelData' );

//jQuery window resize call/event
$window.resize(function resizeScreen() {
    // console.log('window is resizing');

    // here I am resizing my div class height
    $rightPanelData.css( 'height', $window.height() - 166 );
    $leftPanelData.css ( 'height', $window.height() - 236 );
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I consider the jQuery plugin "jQuery resize event" to be the best solution for this as it takes care of throttling the event so that it works the same across all browsers. It's similar to Andrews answer but better since you can hook the resize event to specific elements/selectors as well as the entire window. It opens up new possibilities to write clean code.

The plugin is available [here](http://benalman.com/code/projects/jquery-resize/docs/files/jquery-ba-resize-js.html)

There are performance issues if you add a lot of listeners, but for most usage cases it's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add further control to this:

```
    var disableRes = false;
    var refreshWindow = function() {
        disableRes = false;
        location.reload();
    }
    var resizeTimer;
    if (disableRes == false) {
        jQuery(window).resize(function() {
            disableRes = true;
            clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
            resizeTimer = setTimeout(refreshWindow, 1000);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**hope it will help in jQuery**

define a function first, if there is an existing function skip to next step.

```
 function someFun() {
 //use your code
 }
```

browser resize use like these.

```
 $(window).on('resize', function () {
    someFun();  //call your function.
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the window resize functions mentioned it is important to understand that the resize events fire a lot if used without a deboucing the events.

Paul Irish has an excellent function that debounces the resize calls a great deal. Very recommended to use. Works cross-browser. Tested it in IE8 the other day and all was fine.

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Make sure to [check out the demo](http://www.paulirish.com/demo/resize) to see the difference.

Here is the function for completeness.

```
(function($,sr){

  // debouncing function from John Hann
  // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null;
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
      };
  }
  // smartresize 
  jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');


// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){
  // code that takes it easy...
});
```