# JavaScript window resize event

Tags: javascript, window-resize

How can I hook into a browser window resize event?

There's [a jQuery way of listening for resize events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/599288/cross-browser-window-resize-event-javascript-jquery) but I would prefer not to bring it into my project for just this one requirement.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I dont care about IE, I was thinking more about resizing for opera on a mobile phone.

Answer (score 806, accepted):

Best practice is to add to the resize event, rather than replace it:

```js
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
    ...
}, true);
```

An alternative is to make a single handler for the DOM event (but can only have one), eg.

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

jQuery *may* do some work to ensure that the resize event gets fired consistently in all browsers, but I'm not sure if any of the browsers differ, but I'd encourage you to test in Firefox, Safari, and IE.

Comment: I'm not sure how much work they do on the consistency. In Firefox the event gets called as long as your resizing (it loops) in IE(6?) it will only fire when your done resizing.

Comment: One potential gotcha with this method is that you're overriding the event and so you can't attach multiple actions to an event.  The addEventListener/attachEvent combo is the best way to go to make your javascript play friendly with any other script that might be executing on the page.

Comment: var onresize = window.onresize;
window.onresize = function(event) {
  if (typeof onresize === 'function')
    onresize();
  /** ... */
}

Comment: Nice one @MyItchyChin I used:

    $(window).on('resize', function (e) {
        console.log('message 1');
    });

Comment: Check out the jQuery commented source, there's a lot of good stuff there.

Comment: `window.addEventListener('resize', function(){}, true);`

Comment: @SubOne a perfect example of how one should never do it.

Comment: This is not the way to do this. Hasn't been for a long time. Use `addEventListener` instead so your script doesn't break other scripts on the page.

Comment: **ECMAScript 6**: `window.onresize = () => { /* code */ };` or better: `window.addEventListener('resize', () => { /* code */ });`

Comment: An possible typo could be **document**.addEventListener('resize' ...); **is not document, is window**, then **window**.addEventListener('resize' ...); is the way.

Comment: Overwriting a window function is never a good idea. Use eventListeners for that.

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman - You are missing an important "true" parameter at the end.

Comment: @Ωmega boolean value after function is useCapture, which specifies whether or not the event is captured (given only to this listener).

Comment: @Motes - Shouldn't be that `true` ?

Comment: @Ωmega One will know if one wants to capture event for one's particular usage, usually doesn't matter unless another function uses capture, so probably yes.

Comment: Not sure if I'm doing something hugely wrong here but how would I adapt this so it updated while resizing? Currently it just does it after you've stopped moving the browser? https://jsfiddle.net/z2vu7jg0/

Comment: Thanks! I needed this to get the column headers to resize when the columns of the table body were resized when the browser was resized in a DataTable.net JQuery table:  window.addEventListener('resize', function(event) {
            $($.fn.dataTable.tables(true)).DataTable().columns.adjust();
        }, true);

Answer (score 636):

First off, I know the `addEventListener` method has been mentioned in the comments above, but I didn't see any code. Since it's the preferred approach, here it is:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // do stuff here
});
```

[Here's a working sample](http://codepen.io/jondlm/pen/doijJ).

Comment: This is the most straightforward answer.

Comment: Sounds like the best answer because your not overwriting the window.onresize event :-)

Comment: Many people add anonymous event listeners like you do in this example, but it is not really good practice, because this approach makes it [impossible](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-Registration-interfaces) to remove these listeners later. This used to be no problem because web pages were short-lived anyway, but in this day and age of AJAX and RIAs and SPAs  it's becoming one. We need a way to manage event listeners lifecycle. Thus, It would be better to factor out the listener function into a separate function so it can be removed later with `removeEventListener`.

Comment: why can't everyone answer like this without all the fluff

Comment: alright... this seems more legit for a correct answer

Comment: Choose this one but edit it to say `window.addEventListener('resize', onResize)` and add `window.removeEventListener('resize', onResize)` like @StijndeWitt suggested.

Comment: I think there is truth to both Stijn de Witt's and quemeful's answers here. Sometimes you care about removing event listeners, but in the case that you don't, adding all that extra code like in the example above is unnecessary and can both to bloat and less readability. In my opinion, if you don't envision a reason to need to remove the listener, this approach is the best solution. You can always rewrite it later if necessary. In my experience, these needs only arise in specific situations.

Answer (score 545):

Never override the window.onresize function.

Instead, create a function to add an Event Listener to the object or element.
This checks and incase the listeners don't work, then it overrides the object's function as a last resort. This is the preferred method used in libraries such as jQuery.

`object`: the element or window object
`type`: resize, scroll (event type)
`callback`: the function reference

```
var addEvent = function(object, type, callback) {
    if (object == null || typeof(object) == 'undefined') return;
    if (object.addEventListener) {
        object.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    } else if (object.attachEvent) {
        object.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    } else {
        object["on"+type] = callback;
    }
};
```

Then use is like this:

```
addEvent(window, "resize", function_reference);
```

or with an anonymous function:

```
addEvent(window, "resize", function(event) {
  console.log('resized');
});
```

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. Overriding onresize is just  bad practice.

Comment: hah, what's with all the extra null checks? trying to work in IE 4.5 or something?

Comment: @FlavorScape Late answer: You can specify if you want your page to be *zoomable/resizable* on mobile devices there days. So adding a function for that purpose when it'll never be triggered would be stupid.

Comment: And you are wondering how do I call this function to receive window resize events? Here is how: addEvent(window, "resize", function_reference); :)

Comment: Note that as of IE 11, `attachEvent` is no longer supported. The preferred way for the future is `addEventListener`.

Comment: Be careful with `elem == undefined`. It is possible (although unlikely) that "undefined" is locally defined as something else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175673/jslint-complains-about-redefining-undefined

Comment: ironic when you just did... twice.

Comment: Why doesn't your `addEvent` function allow for the return of the `event` object. In your example, your anonymous function is expecting the `event` object, while the `addEventListener` method you use within `addEvent` does not return it. You should add a parameter: `addEvent = function(object, type, callback, **eventReturn**)` and use this new parameter in your `addEventListenerCall`: `object.addEventListener(type, callback, **eventReturn**);`

Comment: You should also avoid using the JavaScript reserved word `object` as a variable name. The function you have provided will not work in strict mode. I would suggest changing the parameter `object` of your `addEvent` function to "obj" instead.

Comment: I have provided an updated version of your function as another answer. My version includes the fixes I spoke of.

Comment: `object` is not a reserved keyword. `Object` on the other hand is a built in function, so its still save to use.

Comment: Peter-Paul Koch from Quirksmode once held a [competetion](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/10/_and_the_winner_1.html) for who could write the best `addEvent` implementation. To be honest, I wouldn't use it anymore. Just use `addEventListener`. The few legacy browsers that did not support it have been [laid to rest](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/WindowsForBusiness/End-of-IE-support) and support is now pretty much [universal](http://caniuse.com/#feat=addeventlistener).

Comment: @Luke I recently had a problem with an api that returned "undefined" and it confused me for days.

Comment: Never is a really strong word. Especially in programming. If you are writing small scripts to implement a specific need, do whatever you want.

Comment: Just before the `object["on"+type] = callback;` statement, shouldn't you `const previousCallback = object["on"+type] || () => {};` then set `object["on"+type] = () => { previousCallback(); callback(); }`? May want to be mindful of avoiding arrow functions incase use of the `this` keyword is being used..

Comment: Why not just use one already built in?   

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
  // do stuff here
});

Answer (score 65):

**Solution for 2018+:**

You should use [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver). It is a browser-native solution that has a much better performance than to use the `resize` event. In addition, it not only supports the event on the `document` but also on arbitrary `elements`.

> ```
> var ro = new ResizeObserver( entries => {
>   for (let entry of entries) {
>     const cr = entry.contentRect;
>     console.log('Element:', entry.target);
>     console.log(`Element size: ${cr.width}px x ${cr.height}px`);
>     console.log(`Element padding: ${cr.top}px ; ${cr.left}px`);
>   }
> });
>
> // Observe one or multiple elements
> ro.observe(someElement);
> ```

Currently, [Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Edge support it](https://caniuse.com/#feat=resizeobserver). For other (and older) browsers you have to use a [polyfill](https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill).

Comment: any source for the claim "much better performance" please? (I'm not disproving, just asking :))

I know the window:resize fires a lot, but for a simple "if this then that" method it shouldn't slow app down, WDYT?

Comment: With `addEventListener` you only watch the element you are interrested in and with `ResizeObserver` you watch everything, so I wonder how it can be more performant. Also `addEventListener` seems more readable, if you are watching only one element, than looping and finding the good one (should it have an id). Am I missing something ?

Comment: @chovy This is not true => MDN doc states "The ResizeObserver interface reports changes to the dimensions **of an Element's content or border box, or** the bounding box of an SVGElement."

Comment: i didn't reply here.

Answer (score 55):

The resize event should never be used directly as it is fired continuously as we resize.

Use a debounce function to mitigate the excess calls.

`window.addEventListener('resize',debounce(handler, delay, immediate),false);`

Here's a common debounce floating around the net, though do look for more advanced ones as featuerd in lodash.

```
const debounce = (func, wait, immediate) => {
    var timeout;
    return () => {
        const context = this, args = arguments;
        const later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        const callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};
```

This can be used like so...

```
window.addEventListener('resize', debounce(() => console.log('hello'),
200, false), false);
```

It will never fire more than once every 200ms.

For mobile orientation changes use:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', () => console.log('hello'), false);
```

Here's a [small library](https://github.com/julienetie/resizilla) I put together to take care of this neatly.

Comment: I appreciate the information on: debounce (it now seems an invaluable concept/function even though I previously resisted using timeouts in this way), lodash (though I'm personally not convinced) and resolving the ambiguity about whether to use addEvent as a fallback to addEventListener (only because older answers don't really explicitly address the comments regarding this)

Comment: FYI since you are using ES6 arrow func notation, the inner function needs to have `(...arguments) => {...}` (or `...args` for less confusion) as the `arguments` variable is no longer available their scope.

Comment: I'm fully aware, that snippet is not my code, it's just as an example.

Comment: Great answer, the perf issues with resize need to be addressed! Debouncing is an option, another is simple throttling (which might be the way to go if you need your UI to resize in "steps"). See http://bencentra.com/code/2015/02/27/optimizing-window-resize.html for examples

Comment: orientationchange is deprecated

Answer (score 17):

I do believe that the correct answer has already been provided by @Alex V, yet the answer does require some modernization as it is over five years old now.

There are two main issues:

1. Never use `object` as a parameter name. It is a reservered word. With this being said, @Alex V's provided function will not work in `strict mode`.
2. The `addEvent` function provided by @Alex V does not return the `event object` if the `addEventListener` method is used. Another parameter should be added to the `addEvent` function to allow for this.

**NOTE: The new parameter to `addEvent` has been made optional so that migrating to this new function version will not break any previous calls to this function. All legacy uses will be supported.**

Here is the updated `addEvent` function with these changes:

```
/*
    function: addEvent

    @param: obj         (Object)(Required)

        -   The object which you wish
            to attach your event to.

    @param: type        (String)(Required)

        -   The type of event you
            wish to establish.

    @param: callback    (Function)(Required)

        -   The method you wish
            to be called by your
            event listener.

    @param: eventReturn (Boolean)(Optional)

        -   Whether you want the
            event object returned
            to your callback method.
*/
var addEvent = function(obj, type, callback, eventReturn)
{
    if(obj == null || typeof obj === 'undefined')
        return;

    if(obj.addEventListener)
        obj.addEventListener(type, callback, eventReturn ? true : false);
    else if(obj.attachEvent)
        obj.attachEvent("on" + type, callback);
    else
        obj["on" + type] = callback;
};
```

An example call to the new `addEvent` function:

```
var watch = function(evt)
{
    /*
        Older browser versions may return evt.srcElement
        Newer browser versions should return evt.currentTarget
    */
    var dimensions = {
        height: (evt.srcElement || evt.currentTarget).innerHeight,
        width: (evt.srcElement || evt.currentTarget).innerWidth
    };
};

addEvent(window, 'resize', watch, true);
```

Comment: I would argue that attachEvent is no longer relevant in 2017.

Comment: @VladNicula I would agree, but this answer is two years old.

Answer (score 6):

```js
window.onresize = function() {
    // your code
};
```

Comment: As many of the comments above say, it's best not to overwrite the onresize function; rather add a new event. See Jondlm's answer.

Answer (score 5):

The following blog post may be useful to you: [Fixing the window resize event in IE](http://mbccs.blogspot.com/2007/11/fixing-window-resize-event-in-ie.html)

It provides this code:

> ```
> Sys.Application.add_load(function(sender, args) {
>     $addHandler(window, 'resize', window_resize);
> });
>
> var resizeTimeoutId;
>
> function window_resize(e) {
>      window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeoutId);
>      resizeTimeoutId = window.setTimeout('doResizeCode();', 10);
> }
> ```

Comment: This one is applicable to ASP.NET applications only

Answer (score 3):

The already mentioned solutions above will work if all you want to do is resize the window and window only. However, if you want to have the resize propagated to child elements, you will need to propagate the event yourself. Here's some example code to do it:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
  var recResizeElement = function (root) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(root.childNodes, function (el) {

      var resizeEvent = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
      resizeEvent.initEvent("resize", false, true);
      var propagate = el.dispatchEvent(resizeEvent);

      if (propagate)
        recResizeElement(el);
    });
  };
  recResizeElement(document.body);
});
```

Note that a child element can call

```
 event.preventDefault();
```

on the event object that is passed in as the first Arg of the resize event. For example:

```
var child1 = document.getElementById("child1");
child1.addEventListener("resize", function (event) {
  ...
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following approach which is [ok for small projects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769527/860099)

```
<body onresize="yourHandler(event)">
```

```js
function yourHandler(e) {
  console.log('Resized:', e.target.innerWidth)
}
```

```html
<body onresize="yourHandler(event)">
  Content... (resize browser to see)
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script language="javascript">
    window.onresize = function() {
    document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Accordion1').style.height = '100%';
} 

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var EM = new events_managment();

EM.addEvent(window, 'resize', function(win,doc, event_){
    console.log('resized');
    //EM.removeEvent(win,doc, event_);
});

function events_managment(){
    this.events = {};
    this.addEvent = function(node, event_, func){
        if(node.addEventListener){
            if(event_ in this.events){
                node.addEventListener(event_, function(){
                    func(node, event_);
                    this.events[event_](win_doc, event_);
                }, true);
            }else{
                node.addEventListener(event_, function(){
                    func(node, event_);
                }, true);
            }
            this.events[event_] = func;
        }else if(node.attachEvent){

            var ie_event = 'on' + event_;
            if(ie_event in this.events){
                node.attachEvent(ie_event, function(){
                    func(node, ie_event);
                    this.events[ie_event]();
                });
            }else{
                node.attachEvent(ie_event, function(){
                    func(node, ie_event);
                });
            }
            this.events[ie_event] = func;
        }
    }
    this.removeEvent = function(node, event_){
        if(node.removeEventListener){
            node.removeEventListener(event_, this.events[event_], true);
            this.events[event_] = null;
            delete this.events[event_];
        }else if(node.detachEvent){
            node.detachEvent(event_, this.events[event_]);
            this.events[event_] = null;
            delete this.events[event_];
        }
    }
}
```