# How do I register a JS function to run when a browser window is resized?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, events, dom-events, window-resize

How do I register a JS function to run when a browser window is resized?

I assume it's in the

```
Page.ClientScript
```

class methods somewhere, but I am a bit confused.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resizing the browser window requires a client-side script, so it's probably more appropriate to write this directly into .aspx page in a script block, or possibly in a .js file.

That being said, check out this question, you can use a script similar to this: [JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event) via the Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript method.