# Detect viewport orientation, if orientation is Portrait display alert message advising user of instructions

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, viewport, device-orientation

I am building a website specifically for mobile devices. There is one page in particular which is best viewed in landscape mode.

Is there a way to detect if the user visiting that page is viewing it in Portrait mode and if so, display a message informing the user that the page is best viewed in landscape mode? If the user is already viewing it in landscape mode then no message will appear.

So basically, I want the site to detect the viewport orientation, if orientation is **Portrait**, then display an alert message advising the user that this page is best viewed in **Landscape** mode.

Answer (score 336, accepted):

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert("Please use Landscape!");
}
```

jQuery Mobile has an event that handles the change of this property... if you want to warn if someone rotates later - [`orientationchange`](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/events.html)

Also, after some googling, check out `window.orientation` (which is I believe measured in degrees...)

**EDIT**: On mobile devices, if you open a keyboard then the above may fail, so can use `screen.availHeight` and `screen.availWidth`, which gives proper height and width even after the keyboard is opened.

```JS
if(screen.availHeight > screen.availWidth){
    alert("Please use Landscape!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately, it doesn't solve the problem of detecting the orientation of the device and displaying an alert message if the device is in Portrait mode.

Comment: `if(window.height > window.width) alert("please view in landscape");` doesn't work?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. However, the following script did work:

if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
   alert("Please view in landscape");
   }

Comment: I'm having a little trouble getting this working myself. Which element do I need to call this function on? If somebody could post a working example it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This script won't work if there's a metatag %meta{content: "app-id=, app-argument=#{request.url}", name: "apple-itunes-app"}/ on iPhone4 because even in portrait mode x is bigger than y

Comment: this is incorrect. it is relative to how the page loaded if you have fixed or absolute positioned divs.

Comment: I was overcomplexifying the problem. This is great. So simple.

Comment: On many devices, when the keyboard is shown, the availableWidth will be greater than the height, incorrectly giving landscape orientation.

Comment: to make it work `window.orientation` I need to include mobile jquery library in to page?

Comment: It doesn't work because if the keyboard is displayed, window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth is true but you are in portrait mode.

Comment: A great quick solution for simple pages. Note that window.orientation doesn't work on all platforms - if you're using a desktop Chrome browsers, for example, that device has the orientation often undefined.

Comment: @Eric The question was regarding mobile devices. Desktop Chrome is irrelevant.

Comment: This doesn't work if combined with the `orientationchange` event. It will show the old orientation instead of the new orientation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734939/4284627) works well combined with the `orientationchange` event.

Comment: Maybe `window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? "LANDSCAPE" : "PORTRAIT"`

Comment: window.orientation deprecated https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation

Comment: This actually doesn't work when bringing up the keyboard on some OSes. The keyboard popup will make this information flip even though they are still in the same orientation. Going by screen size doesn't work.

I highly recommend everyone uses: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation
AKA: screen.orientation.type

Answer (score 245):

You can also use `window.matchMedia`, which I use and prefer as it closely resembles CSS syntax:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
   // you're in PORTRAIT mode
}

if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
   // you're in LANDSCAPE mode
}
```

Tested on iPad 2.

Comment: Support for that feature is kinda weak though: http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia

Comment: In Firefox for Android works properly only after the DOM ready event for me.

Comment: Support for this is much stronger now.  This seems to be a much more robust answer now then the accepted one.

Comment: Beware of this with this (link) solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883163/css-media-query-soft-keyboard-breaks-css-orientation-rules-alternative-solut

Comment: This is the correct answer now. This feature has full support for all relevant browsers.

Comment: This falls prey to the issue where the android keyboard causes the width to exceed the height, the browser will report landscape. - mentioned by @dzv3

Comment: This doesn't work if combined with the `orientationchange` event. It will show the old orientation instead of the new orientation. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11734939/4284627) works well combined with the `orientationchange` event.

Comment: I've seen this fail on Android webview when checked too soon. It sometimes takes a bit for the height to be registered. If document.documentElement.clientHeight = 0 then this check will always say landscape. Same for the width/height comparison check, of course.

Comment: this doesn't work in Android with keyboard visible. To get rid of it without breaking iOS: `window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches || (window.outerWidth != screen.availHeight && screen.availHeight > screen.availWidth)`

Answer (score 113):

David Walsh has a better and to the point approach.

```
// Listen for orientation changes
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  // Announce the new orientation number
  alert(window.orientation);
}, false);
```

During these changes, the window.orientation property may change. A value of 0 means portrait view, -90 means a the device is landscape rotated to the right, and 90 means the device is landscape rotated to the left.

http://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change

Comment: On the Nexus 10, and I don't know about other Android 10" tablets, the values are backwards. I.e. 0 is returned when the device is in landscape, not portrait. tobyodavies's answer above seems to work well though across all devices I've tested

Comment: Orientation 0 is given to be the "natural" orientation of the device, and thus is vendor-dependent. It could be portrait or landscape...

Comment: on ipad in iframe did not alert anything

Comment: this is not good solution for detection orientation mod of device. Because they return value depend of natural device orientation. Example on Samsung 7' tablet portrait view return 90 but on nexus 4   for portrait they return 0.

Comment: Not all devices will report the same values: https://notes.matthewgifford.com/a-misconception-about-window-orientation-7231235a94c2#.llqebngde

Comment: On this link: https://notes.matthewgifford.com/a-misconception-about-window-orientation-7231235a94c2#.llqebngde

The author showcase different devices from different manufacturers have different interpretation of what is landscape and portrait. Hence different reported values, which you cannot really rely on.

Comment: orientation is unsupported in iOS

Comment: orientationchange is deprecated

Answer (score 41):

You can use CSS3 :

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape)
{
   body
   {
      background: red;
   }
}
```

Comment: Best answer to me, because you don't need a listener for changed orientation. Although I combine it with modernizr to detect if it is a touch-device, since it makes no sense on desktop or laptop screens. Still not ok for such screens WITH touch capabilities...

Comment: Not related to javascript. OP needs javascript solution.

Comment: No, he wants to display a message, you can use display:none then display:block to display something.

Comment: What is the support like for this CSS check?

Comment: I dont know, but I didnt find a mobile that doesnot support it. Also it seems broken on old Android, when keyboard shows up sometimes the media query is trigged.

Comment: Unfortunately although this is pretty awesome, as Thomas said I found that on iPhone and Android when the keyboard comes up the media query is triggered, if anyone has an answer I raised the issue [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33357414/css-media-query-to-detect-landscape-only-on-mobile-iphone-android)

Comment: This is great, not giving me any issues when activating the keyboard.

Answer (score 26):

There are a few ways to do it, for example:

- Check `window.orientation` value
- Compare `innerHeight` vs. `innerWidth`

You can adapt one of the methods below.

---

**Check if device is in portrait mode**

```
function isPortrait() {
    return window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth;
}
```

**Check if device is in landscape mode**

```
function isLandscape() {
    return (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90);
}
```

**Example usage**

```
if (isPortrait()) {
    alert("This page is best viewed in landscape mode");
}
```

---

**How do I detect the orientation change?**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('orientationchange', function(event) {
        console.log(orientation);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

I think the more stable solution is to use screen instead of window, because it could be both - landscape or portrait if you will resize your browser window on desktop computer.

```
if (screen.height > screen.width){
    alert("Please use Landscape!");
}
```

Comment: This works in IE 10, Firefox 23 and Chrome 29 (all desktop browsers).

Comment: All major browsers support it. IE 7 as well

Comment: not standard, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.screen#Specification

Comment: @Duncan No. It works on mobile. It is a pretty old method and it's supported on old safari and android browsers. It may be not very accurate with retina but for detecting viewport orientation it should work fine

Comment: @artnikpro I tested it yesterday and it appears that Safari returns the physical screen dimensions neglecting the orientation. So screen.width is always the physical width of the screen.

Answer (score 10):

In order to apply all of these great comments to my daily coding, for continuity between all my applications, I have decided to use the following in both my jquery and jquery mobile code.

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
  applyOrientation();
}

function applyOrientation() {
  if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {
    alert("You are now in portrait");
  } else {
    alert("You are now in landscape");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

**CCS only**

```
@media (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait){ /* tablet and smaller */
  body:after{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    background: #212121 url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/sValK.png) 0 0 no-repeat; /* replace with an image that tells the visitor to rotate the device to landscape mode */
    background-size: 100% auto;
    opacity: 0.95;
  }
}
```

In some cases you may want to add a small piece of code to reload to page after the visitor rotated the device, so that the CSS is rendered properly:

```
window.onorientationchange = function() { 
    var orientation = window.orientation; 
        switch(orientation) { 
            case 0:
            case 90:
            case -90: window.location.reload(); 
            break; } 
};
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to but I had to say thanks for this, it's a great solve.

Comment: as of 2021, it's supported in all modern browsers https://caniuse.com/?search=media%20orientation

Answer (score 8):

Don't try fixed window.orientation queries (0, 90 etc doesn't mean portrait, landscape etc):

http://www.matthewgifford.com/blog/2011/12/22/a-misconception-about-window-orientation/

Even on iOS7 depending how you come into the browser 0 isn't always portrait

Comment: i don't think this is true anymore

Comment: It is still true... cannot assume anything from pure `orientation.angle`. You need to check also `orientation.type` and this makes it bit complicated.

Answer (score 7):

I combined two solutions and it works fine for me.

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {                   
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches) {
       alert("PORTRAIT")
     }
    if (window.matchMedia("(orientation: landscape)").matches) {
      alert("LANSCAPE")
     }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 7):

I disagree with the most voted answer. Use `screen` and not `window`

```
    if(screen.innerHeight > screen.innerWidth){
    alert("Please use Landscape!");
}
```

Is the proper way to do it. If you calculate with `window.height`, you ll have trouble on Android. When keyboard is open, window shrinks. So use screen instead of window.

The `screen.orientation.type` is a good answer but with IE. 
https://caniuse.com/#search=screen.orientation

Comment: As of Mar 2021, there is no screen.innerHeight ... on Chrome at least.  There is a screen.availHeight.  And screen.height exists too.

Comment: Same for Firefox, there is [screen.availHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/availHeight) and [screen.availWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/availWidth) which [works for all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=Screen.avail)

Answer (score 7):

```
$(window).on("orientationchange",function( event ){
    alert(screen.orientation.type)
});
```

Comment: unfortunately not supported by Safari

Answer (score 5):

After some experimentation I have found that rotating an orientation aware device will always trigger a browser window's `resize` event.  So in your resize handler simply call a function like:

```
function is_landscape() {
  return (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight);
}
```

Comment: See above as to why 90 => landscape isn't something you can rely on across different devices.

Answer (score 4):

iOS doens't update `screen.width` & `screen.height` when orientation changes. Android doens't update `window.orientation` when it changes.

My solution to this problem:

```
var isAndroid = /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent);

if(isAndroid)
{
    if(screen.width < screen.height){
        //portrait mode on Android
    }
} else {
    if(window.orientation == 0){
        //portrait mode iOS and other devices
    }
}
```

You can detect this change in orientation on Android as well as iOS with the following code:

```
var supportsOrientationChange = "onorientationchange" in window,
    orientationEvent = supportsOrientationChange ? "orientationchange" : "resize";

window.addEventListener(orientationEvent, function() {
    alert("the orientation has changed");
}, false);
```

If the `onorientationchange` event is not supported, the event bound will be the `resize` event.

Answer (score 3):

Get the orientation (at any time in your js code) via

```
window.orientation
```

When `window.orientation` returns `0` or `180` then you are in **portrait mode**, when returning `90` or `270` then you are in **landscape mode**.

Comment: It doesn't return 270 though, it returns -90.

Comment: @FelipeCorrea The answer is 2 years old!

Comment: I was clarifying to make it valid for new visitors. It helped me btw.

Comment: window.orientation is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

If you have the latest browsers `window.orientation` might not work. In that case use following code for getting angle -

```
var orientation = window.screen.orientation.angle;
```

This is still an experimental technology, you can check the browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/orientation#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 2):

```
//see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event
//see also http://mbccs.blogspot.com/2007/11/fixing-window-resize-event-in-ie.html
/*
Be wary of this:
While you can just hook up to the standard window resize event, you'll find that in IE, the event is fired once for every X and once for every Y axis movement, resulting in a ton of events being fired which might have a performance impact on your site if rendering is an intensive task.
*/

//setup 
window.onresize = function(event) {
    window_resize(event);
}

//timeout wrapper points with doResizeCode as callback
function window_resize(e) { 
     window.clearTimeout(resizeTimeoutId); 
     resizeTimeoutId = window.setTimeout('doResizeCode();', 10); 
}

//wrapper for height/width check
function doResizeCode() {
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        alert("Please view in landscape");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

another alternative to determine orientation, based on comparison of the width/height:

```
var mql = window.matchMedia("(min-aspect-ratio: 4/3)");
if (mql.matches) {
     orientation = 'landscape';
}
```

You use it on "resize" event:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function() { ... });
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best method I found, based on David Walsh's article ([Detect Orientation Change on Mobile Devices](https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change))

```
if ( window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)").matches ) {  
   alert("Please use Landscape!") 
}
```

---

**Explanation:**

[Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) is a native method that allows you to define a media query rule and check its validity at any point in time.

I find it useful to attach an `onchange` listener on the return value of this method. Example:

```
var mediaQueryRule = window.matchMedia("(orientation: portrait)")
mediaQueryRule.onchange = function(){ alert("screen orientation changed") }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a way by which you can detect if user flipped their device to portrait mode using `screen.orientation`

Just use the bellow code:

```
screen.orientation.onchange = function () {
     var type = screen.orientation.type;
     if (type.match(/portrait/)) {
         alert('Please flip to landscape, to use this app!');
     }
}
```

Now, `onchange` will get fired when ever user flips the device and alert will pop-up when user using portrait mode.

Answer (score 2):

Some devices don't provide the `orientationchange` event, but do fire the window's resize event:

```
// Listen for resize changes
window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
    // Get screen size (inner/outerWidth, inner/outerHeight)

}, false);
```

A bit less obvious than the orientationchange event, but works very well. [Please check here](https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to tobyodavies for guiding the way.

To achieve an alert message based on the mobile device's orientation you need to implement the following script within the `function setHeight() {`

```
if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
    alert("Please view in landscape");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 270, it can be -90 (minus 90).

Answer (score 1):

This expands on a previous answer. The best solution I've found is to make an innocuous CSS attribute that only appears if a CSS3 media query is met, and then have the JS test for that attribute.

So for instance, in the CSS you'd have:

```
@media screen only and (orientation:landscape)
{
    //  Some innocuous rule here
    body
    {
        background-color: #fffffe;
    }
}
@media screen only and (orientation:portrait)
{
    //  Some innocuous rule here
    body
    {
        background-color: #fffeff;
    }
}
```

You then go to JavaScript (I'm using jQuery for funsies). Color declarations may be weird, so you may want to use something else, but this is the most foolproof method I've found for testing it. You can then just use the resize event to pick up on switching. Put it all together for:

```
function detectOrientation(){
    //  Referencing the CSS rules here.
    //  Change your attributes and values to match what you have set up.
    var bodyColor = $("body").css("background-color");
    if (bodyColor == "#fffffe") {
        return "landscape";
    } else
    if (bodyColor == "#fffeff") {
        return "portrait";
    }
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    var orientation = detectOrientation();
    alert("Your orientation is " + orientation + "!");
    $(document).resize(function(){
        orientation = detectOrientation();
        alert("Your orientation is " + orientation + "!");
    });
});
```

The best part of this is that as of my writing this answer, it doesn't appear to have any effect on desktop interfaces, since they (generally) don't (seem to) pass any argument for orientation to the page.

Comment: As a note Windows 10 and Edge might be throwing a wrench into this - I haven't done substantial testing on the new platform yet, but at least initially, it seems like it might be supplying orientation data to the browser. It's still possible to build your site around it, but it is definitely something to be aware of.

Answer (score 1):

I used for Android Chrome ["The Screen Orientation API"](https://www.w3.org/TR/screen-orientation)

To look the current orientation call console.log(screen.orientation.type) (and maybe screen.orientation.angle).

Results: portrait-primary | portrait-secondary | landscape-primary | landscape-secondary

Below is my code, I hope it'll be helpful:

```
var m_isOrientation = ("orientation" in screen) && (typeof screen.orientation.lock == 'function') && (typeof screen.orientation.unlock == 'function');
...
if (!isFullscreen()) return;
screen.orientation.lock('landscape-secondary').then(
    function() {
        console.log('new orientation is landscape-secondary');
    },
    function(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
);//here's Promise
...
screen.orientation.unlock();
```

- I tested only for Android Chrome - ok

Answer (score 1):

```
screen.orientation.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
 console.log(screen.orientation.type + " " + screen.orientation.angle);
}, false);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem in the original question. It shows how to log orientation changes, but it does not show how to display a message only in one particular orientation.

Answer (score 1):

The window object in JavaScript on iOS devices has an orientation property that can be used to determine the rotation of the device. The following shows the values window.orientation for iOS devices (e.g. iPhone, iPad, iPod) at different orientations.

This solution also works for android devices as well. I checked in android native browser (Internet browser) and in the Chrome browser, even in the old versions of it.

```
function readDeviceOrientation() {                      
    if (Math.abs(window.orientation) === 90) {
        // Landscape
    } else {
        // Portrait
    }
}
```

Comment: window.orientation is Deprecated!
[MDN Window.orientation property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/orientation)

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use.

```
function getOrientation() {

    // if window.orientation is available...
    if( window.orientation && typeof window.orientation === 'number' ) {

        // ... and if the absolute value of orientation is 90...
        if( Math.abs( window.orientation ) == 90 ) {

              // ... then it's landscape
              return 'landscape';

        } else {

              // ... otherwise it's portrait
              return 'portrait';

        }

    } else {

        return false; // window.orientation not available

    }

}
```

Implementation

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {

     // if orientation is landscape...
     if( getOrientation() === 'landscape' ) {

         // ...do your thing

    }

}, false);
```

Comment: Your code have a mistake:

 // if window.orientation is available...
    if( window.orientation && typeof window.orientation === 'number' ) {

the if in and doesn't work if window.orientation=0

Answer (score 0):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <title>Rotation Test</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"></style>
  <script src="js/jquery-1.5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
            // Get screen size (inner/outerWidth, inner/outerHeight)
            var height = $(window).height();
            var width = $(window).width();

            if(width>height) {
              // Landscape
              $("#mode").text("LANDSCAPE");
            } else {
              // Portrait
              $("#mode").text("PORTRAIT");
            }
        }, false);

  </script>
 </head>
 <body onorientationchange="updateOrientation();">
   <div id="mode">LANDSCAPE</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note about `window.orientation` is that it will return `undefined` if you are not on a mobile device. So a good function to check for the orientation might look like this, where `x` is `window.orientation`:

```
//check for orientation
function getOrientation(x){
  if (x===undefined){
    return 'desktop'
  } else {
    var y;
    x < 0 ? y = 'landscape' : y = 'portrait';
    return y;
  }
}
```

Call it like so:

```
var o = getOrientation(window.orientation);
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  o = getOrientation(window.orientation);
  console.log(o);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just use this..

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
    if (window.orientation == "90" || window.orientation == "-90") {
        //Do stuff
    }
}, false);
```

Comment: It's better to add `window.orientation === 90` test egality between number and string is not sure.

Answer (score 0):

As you know when device is portrait the width is lower than height of screen.
And when device is landscape the height is lower than width of screen
so this will be the code :

```
var isPortrait = window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight ? false : true;
```