# Jquery resize image in responsive template not working on Iphone

Tags: jquery, resize

In a responsive template i have some jquery code to calculate the height of an image proportionally to the screen size. It works in all browser but on Iphone/Ipad when I change from portrait do landscape the image does'nt resize, here is the code, hope someone could help me!
Thanks

> // for the body resize  $(document).ready(function() {
>       var bodywidth = $(document).width();  var ratioheight = (bodywidth/3.582);
>       $("#gallery").height(ratioheight); });
>
> // for the body resize active $(window).resize(function() {
>       var bodywidth = $(document).width();  var ratioheight = (bodywidth/3.582);
>       $("#gallery").height(ratioheight); });

Answer (score 0):

are you using jQuery mobile? if so there is an event to detect orientation change called `orientationchange`

Or taken from [Detect viewport orientation, if orientation is Portrait display alert message advising user of instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad)

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  // Announce the new orientation number
  alert(window.orientation);
}, false);
```

Effectively your code should be something like this

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange resize', function(event){
      if(event.orientation) {
            if(event.orientation == 'portrait') {
          // do something
              } else if (event.orientation == 'landscape') {
                       // do something else 
                       } 
            } else {
                  // optional... PC-version javascript for example
                  }

      });
```

Comment: Thanks Mohammed, interesting solution but it seems it does'nt work with var bodywidth = $(document).width(); var ratioheight = (bodywidth / 3.582); Do you hane any idea how to keep alive jquery functions in Iphone/Ipad ?

Comment: Still having problem changing from portrait to landscape, the image does'nt resize to fit the width of the window, can I have some help to find out the right solution? Thanks

Comment: Can you put it somewhere on a URL so that I can test on my phone