# Can I determine if a device is in portrait or landscape mode using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait

I want to conditionally alter what the user sees on the photo gallery web site I'm going to create based on if the device being used to view the site is in portrait/vertical vs. landscape/horizontal mode/orientation. Is this possible?

Comment: This previous answer might help:

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad)

Comment: All good answers; I'm not sure which one to prefer yet. Actually, I also need to know whether the device is a "phone" or not. Here's the method behind my madness: I will have two "views" - one with vertical thumbnails and full-size photos, the other with landscape thumbnails and full-size photos. If the device is a phone, I want it to toggle between those modes based on orientation. For a larger device, though (such as a laptop or desktop), I want to allow the user to explicitly choose which orientation photos they want to see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the `orientationchange` event handler, something like this:

```
$(window).bind("orientationchange", function(evt){
    alert(evt.orientation);
});
```

Here's the [jQuery Mobile entry](http://api.jquerymobile.com/orientationchange/) on detecting and firing the `orientationchange` event.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. Corrected it to evt.orientation.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just changing the layout, consider [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries#orientation) instead.

In Chrome 7 and Firefox 3.6, there is the [`deviceorientation` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Mozilla_event_reference/deviceorientation) which you can listen to.

---

In response to your comment, a simple way of detecting tablets and phones is to detect the screen resolution and size. Tablets generally have higher display resolutions than phones. Media Queries can determine these factors.

As for tablet-phone options

- If your device is a phone, you can toggle CSS using Media Queries based on device orientation.
- If the device is a tablet, you can toggle the CSS using JS using the body id/class switching or by swapping out stylesheets.