# Zurb foundation fire event when changing orientation?

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation

Is there anyway to detect when the orientation of the user's screen changes?

I'd like to fire some javascript functions when this happens to update various bits of content.

For example, I have a set of divs displayed as an accordion.  Each div displays +/- icons to show / hide its content.

When the page loads in landscape, the content in each div is displayed by default, however when it loads in portrait the content is hidden.

I need to reset the +/- icons when the orientation of the screen changes.

Are there any events I can hook into to achieve this?

Any advice appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Zurb has the following classes which might be useful show-for-landscape and show-for-portrait.
See the documentation here:
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html

Comment: Using Javascript : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad

Using Jquery :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980680/can-i-determine-if-a-device-is-in-portrait-or-landscape-mode-using-jquery