# Detect if device is in landscape using deviceorientation

Tags: javascript, accelerometer, device-orientation

using

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', handleOrientation);
```

to listen for device orientation

I know I need to find the alpha of device
(0 - 360)
but don't know what range to use to find out if the phone is in landscape mode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15980680/can-i-determine-if-a-device-is-in-portrait-or-landscape-mode-using-jquery

Comment: Thanks that first link did it

Comment: @epascarello the question that is marked as duplicate is totally different from what the OP is asking here. I agree this is related to device orientation but the OP is specifically asking for `deviceorientation` event which none of the answers provide, but rather suggest other events. Those are not going to work for a PWA and only `deviceorientation` will work. So I request to reopen this.

Comment: @RajshekarReddy Question is over 3 years old, and did you see the comment above yours. LOL

Comment: @epascarello I understand that, Nothing offense. But now since PWA is in the market this event is required for the installed app to trigger orientation change to work. That is the reason I thought it would be a better option to reopen this..

Comment: Again, 3 years old... it was answered back than. And I am willing to bet another question has the answer you are talking about so find it and link that one too....

Comment: I did search but no luck. Anyways if I do find one i'll link it here...

Answer (score -1):

You should check the **alpha** value from the event.

```
function handleOrientation (event) {
    if (event.alpha>89 && event.alpha<150) {//the device is landscape at 90
        console.log("Device is landscape");
    };

}
```

Comment: Hi Thanks this works but only if I tilt to the left

Comment: this is simply not true