# Javascript Alert on mobile devices based orientation

Tags: javascript, alert, device-orientation

I'm trying to alert mobile device users on my site to use their devices in landscape mode. I have an alert pop up but it seems to be getting caught in an infinite loop. How would I go about stopping that loop after the user has clicked ok?

Here is the code:

```
window.ondeviceorientation = detectIPadOrientation;
function detectIPadOrientation () 
{
    if ( orientation == 0 || orientation == 180 ){
        alert ('Please use your iPad in landscape mode'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, telling people what to do with their device isn't exactly a UX "best practice."

Comment: It's only for a specific page not for the entire site. @Pointy

Comment: Perhaps this has to do with how quickly iOS rechecks screen position - over and over I presume.  You could set a flag that would ensure it only pops up one time.  `var pop=true;`  `if(orientation... && pop){alert(...); pop=false};}`

Answer (score 2):

The following code will send an alert based on screen orientation. The alert will only be sent if the screen is in landscape mode.

```
window.onload = function() {
    if ( window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180 ) { 
        alert ('Please use your mobile device in landscape mode'); 
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the website alert users who are using a mobile device, not just when the device is in landscape.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/javascript-solution-to-detect-mobile-browser) will probably help you out.

---

Or, the answer to your exact question might be on [this duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad).

---

You may also try identifying the the user with

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) != null;
```

And sending him an alert if this does not equal `NULL`

I hope this helped you out.

Comment: Instead I used the following code `window.onload=function(){if ( window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180 ){ alert ('Please use your iPad in landscape mode'); }}`

Comment: Okay, if that method worked then post it as an answer. Congratulations. Have a good day.