# Specific JS for ipad portrait is also firing in landscape

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, css

**JS**

```
if (screen.width <= 768 && screen.width != 1024) { 
     jQuery('.menu-link').bind("click touchstart", function() {
          if (jQuery('#wrap3').css("left") === "0px"){
              jQuery('#wrap3').animate({"left":"17%"}, 50);
          }
          else {
              jQuery('#wrap3').animate({"left":"0"}, 50)
          }
     });
  }
```

I originally tried it like this

`if (screen.width <= 768)`

It works fine in portrait, but it works in landscape, when it shouldn't.

**How can I fix this?**

It also doesn't work on desktop which is what I wanted.

On a side note - is this the common practice for creating different JS for different mobile widths? The reason I am using JS instead of CSS3 is because the animations I'm trying to do did not work on ipad.

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like checking the height vs width?

```
if (window.innerheight>window.innerWidth)
{
    alert("Landscape Please!");
}
```

Source:  [Detect viewport orientation, if orientation is Portrait display alert message advising user of instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad)

Comment: Doesn't work. It actually doesn't work at all even in portrait mode. Thanks though