# write jquery code only for ipad porttrait

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, html, ipad

My mobile design is different from desktop, so I need to change some structure for ipad portrait. Now with my code written below it effects both on portrait and landscape. I need a script which will do some actions only for ipad portrait and even when I change orientation in this case also code work only for portrait.

Here is my code:

```
function orient() {  
        if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) {
            // some actions
        }else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
            // some actions
        }
    }

    $(function(){
        orient();
    });

    $(window).bind( 'orientationchange', function(e){
        orient();
    });
```

Comment: Use `matchMedia`, take a look at this => [matchMedia](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad)

Comment: So the actual question is how to detect the orientation?

Comment: via above code I can detect, but when I change orientation it does same thing for landscape on IPAD @m02ph3u5