# Detect iPad device orientation using javascript

Tags: javascript, ipad, orientation

I am using the following code to check the orientation of the iPad. This method is getting called only when i rotate the device or change the orientation of iPad. If a launched the app in landscape mode and when i navigate to this screen the below method is not getting called. How can i detect the orientation of the iPad without rotating the iPad.

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function (event) {
    if (event.orientation == "landscape") {
        set frame for landscape
    } else {
        set frame for portrait
    }
});
```

Comment: Use `trigger`. This will trigger the event and make the handler run. `$(window).trigger('orientationchange')`;

Comment: `window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth;` seems like an easy solution ?

Comment: check this answer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad

Comment: BTW, you're missing `)` of the `bind`

Answer (score 0):

This will check the iPad existence and then compare the height with width.

```
var isiPad = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1

//or
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
var isiPad = /iPad/i.test(ua)
if (isiPad) {
$(window).on('load orientationchange', function(event) {
    if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        console.log("portrait");
    } else {
        console.log("landscape");
    }
});
}
```

Comment: This will be all the devices and not the ipad only. It will even work for mobile devices

Answer (score 0):

This should work too:

```
$(window).bind('orientationchange', function(event) {
  alert('new orientation:' + event.orientation);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).on('load orientationchange', function(event) {
    if(event.orientation == "landscape")
    {
        set frame for landscape
    }
    else
    {
        set frame for portrait
    }
});
```

Add `load` event as well. This will help if the **screen** in question is available in DOM when `window.load` is triggered. Else `trigger` the event after the *screen* is injected to DOM dynamically(as suggested by @Tushar).

> Keep in mind that `orientation change` or `resize` events will not be
>   triggered as page loads initially, if you want to run them initially you will
>   have to include `load` event as well. Or `trigger` them later if its
>   dependent on dynamic parts of DOM.

Comment: Replace last `}` by `)`;