# Detect phone rotation in Javascript Windows Phone mobile application

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, windows-phone, device-orientation

I am writing a mobile application for Windows Phone in HTML5. I want to detect the phone's rotation around the z-axis (I mean the rotation that is used for example in Doodle jump to make the character jump to the left or to the right).

In my application, a line that is vertical in the screen must remain vertical (absolute position in the real world) if I rotate the screen to the left or to the right. To accomplish this, I use the relative values of the angle: each time the screen is rotated a little, I rotate the points of the line by the same amount, but negative.

This works PERFECTLY if the phone is laying on a table or almost horizontal, but the behaviour is much less precise if for example I watch the phone in front of me. Anyway this is not a big problem of course because most users watch the phone from up to down, but a game like doodle jump behaves perfectly also in this situation.

Here is part of the code:

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", handleOrientation, true);

function handleOrientation(event) {

    alphaDiff = Math.floor(event.alpha) - alphaOld;
    alphaOld = Math.floor(event.alpha);

    //Rotation of the vertical line (x1,y1) - (x2,y2) around the center of the screen

    var newPoint = rotate(225, 400, x1, y1, alphaDiff);

    x1 = newPoint[0];
    y1 = newPoint[1];

    newPoint = rotate(225, 400, x2, y2, alphaDiff);

    x2 = newPoint[0];
    y2 = newPoint[1];
}

function rotate(cx, cy, x, y, angle) {

    var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * angle;
    cos = Math.cos(radians);
    sin = Math.sin(radians);
    nx = (cos * (x - cx)) - (sin * (y - cy)) + cx;
    ny = (sin * (x - cx)) + (cos * (y - cy)) + cy;

    return [nx, ny];
}
```

Comment: are you using relative and absolute in your styling?

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad

Comment: @user2242618 does not work on windows phone and kindle

Comment: Looks like the ideal solution is to combine all three (alpha, beta and gamma) in a similar manner shown in my code. It'll take time though.

Comment: I have also tried with alphaDiff = x, like you suggest in your answer's comment, but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried `beta` (for the x-axis) or `gamma` (for the y-axis)?

e.g.

```
function handleOrientation(event) {
    var absolute = event.absolute;
    var alpha    = event.alpha; // z-axis
    var beta     = event.beta;  // x-axis
    var gamma    = event.gamma; // y-axis

    // Do stuff with the new orientation data
}
```

> ### Orientation Values Explained
>
> The value reported for each axis indicates the amount of rotation around a given axis in reference to a standard coordinate frame.
>
> - The `DeviceOrientationEvent.alpha` value represents the motion of the device around the **z-axis**, represented in degrees with values ranging from `0` to `360`.
> - The `DeviceOrientationEvent.beta` value represents the motion of the device around the **x-axis**, represented in degrees with values ranging from `-180` to `180`. This represents a front to back motion of the device.
> - The `DeviceOrientationEvent.gamma` value represents the motion of the device around the **y-axis**, represented in degrees with values ranging from `-90` to `90`. This represents a left to right motion of the device.

[image: Explanation]

---

It also worth checking [browser compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=deviceorientation) for this API.

---

As well as `deviceorientation`, you can check `compassneedscalibration` and `devicemotion`. For more details on `deviceorientation` see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Orientation_and_motion_data_explained#Earth_coordinate_frame).

Comment: Maybe what you are suggesting here is that I should use alpha when the phone is almost horizontal, and beta (or gamma) if it is vertical?

Comment: Read up on the subject more and [from this article](https://dev.opera.com/articles/w3c-device-orientation-usage/) I found that using Euler angles is limited especially due to gimbal lock. Instead you achieve better results converting to Quaternion angles. Created a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/u01jmg3/pen/WRxJEX) to illustrate what I mean. Will update my answer if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: @Sean: did my CodePen help?

Answer (score 0):

A combination of `beta` and `gamma` seems to give pretty good results.
Basically, I normalize the values to a specific range and get the ratio.

```
window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event){
    var b = Math.abs(event.beta)/90;
    if(b>1) b = 2-b;

    var g = event.gamma/90;
    if(Math.abs(event.beta)>90) g = -g;

    var x = g/Math.max(0.25,b);
});
```

The final value is in `x`, positive means right, negative means left.
It works with the phone held horizontally or at any angle facing you.

**Update:** To make the detection work in a vertical position, the code calculates how much the phone is leaning and to which direction.
The value in `x` is always positive if the phone is leaning right and negative if leaning left.

This example shows a blue box in the middle of the screen and moves it to whichever direction the phone is leaning:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><meta name="viewport" content="width=1000,user-scalable=no"/></head>
    <body style="margin:0">
        <pre id="log" style="font-size:4em;"></pre>
        <div id="box" style="background:#69c;width:100px;height:100px;position:relative;left:450px"></div>
        <script>
            var box = document.getElementById("box");
            var log = document.getElementById("log");
            var smoothx = 0;
            window.addEventListener("deviceorientation", function(event){
                var b = Math.abs(event.beta)/90;
                if(b>1) b = 2-b;

                var g = event.gamma/90;
                if(Math.abs(event.beta)>90) g = -g;

                var x = g/Math.max(0.25,b);
                smoothx = smoothx*0.7+x*0.3;

                box.style.left = Math.max(0, Math.min(900, smoothx*500+450))+"px";
                log.innerText = x.toFixed(1)+"\n"+smoothx.toFixed(1);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Because the sensor seems to be very sensitive to movement, I implemented a simple smoothing that gives a steadier value in `smoothx`.
Use `x` for immediate value without smoothing.

Comment: Hello, could you please tell me how your code would change in the case of relative angles? Each time the device orientation changes, I calculate the difference in this way: angleDiff = Math.floor(event.alpha) - alphaOld;          alphaOld = Math.floor(event.alpha);   but if I just replace (event.alpha) with your x variable it does not work.

Comment: @Sean The `x` in my code is always relative. So I suppose you can use `angleDiff = x`. Do you need a working example? I'll update my answer if you do.

Comment: @Sean Apparently I was thinking of a different code. I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. @Ray Radin