# How to target tablet landscape with css or js

Tags: javascript, css

Is there some solution for target all tablets landscape or portrait with css without media queries for each tablet. What is the best solution. I found a lot media queries for tablets. Is there some simple solution. Is there some solution with js for targeting tablets landscape.

Comment: Using media queries ***is*** the simple solution

Comment: Why do you not want to use media queries?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad

Comment: There is media queries for ipad, ipad pro, ipad 10" , galaxy tabs....., for one css property need to write to meny queries, and there is many tablets where code dont work....

Comment: This is very useful qustion, i need professional solution....

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried orientation ?

[ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation ]

Comment: When use orientation that target all device include desktop, ipad pro have 1024px x 1366px rezolution