# How to add window orientation listeners in EXTJS?

Tags: extjs

How to define window orientation listener that is attached only to specific view?
For example if a mobile device is oriented in portrait orientation, I wouild like to show two columns of the grid, and otherwise I would show more columns.

After searching for solution, I found the idea [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad) and [here](https://davidwalsh.name/orientation-change)

However, I do not know how I can add listener to that event, and specifically that listener should be valid only for specific view, and not for the whole application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Viewport`s 'orientationchange' event handler in the 'initialize'  of your view, something like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
            title: 'My Panel',
            fullscreen: true,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                label: "Orientation",
                listeners: {
                    initialize: function (field) {
                        Ext.Viewport.on('orientationchange', function (viewPort, newOrientation, width, height) {
                            field.setValue(newOrientation);
                        });
                    }
                }

            }]
        });
```