# Popup window content refreshes once the window is maximized

Tags: javascript

When I open a popup window with large content in IE, the popup window comes with a scrollbar to fit the content. But when I maximize the page in that case it also remains the same. It is a page with frameset and frames. So is it possible the resize the frame?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the below link. its very useful your question

[Resizing an iframe based on content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/153152/resizing-an-iframe-based-on-content)

Here Frame Resize the depends upon  the content. Then you can make it

```
window.onresize
```

The popup is shown wanted size. May be you feel complex to give particular size of window.
Try to make resize same time of frame resizing.

I Hope its helps to you