# How to minimise pop up window automatically after minimising main window

Tags: javascript, asp.net

how to minimise pop up window automatically after minimising main window in asp.net.

Thanks!

Comment: The browser is not yours. It's *mine*. Stop trying to mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

[Minimize/Maximize a Browser Window](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471151/MinimizeMaximize-a-Browser-Window.htm)

Answer (score 0):

set its height and width as minimum you wants and set its X and Y position to 0.

```
function poponload()
{
    testwindow = window.open("", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,width=100,height=10");
    testwindow.moveTo(0, 0);
}
```

References: [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml)

Check this one also : [resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)