# Perform action when browser toolbars change

Tags: javascript, browser, height

I would like to be able to perform some action when adding or removing toolbars from the browser window. This should be done using Javascript. Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

You can't know this. You can probably figure out, which i suspect you were hinting at was looking at the window resizing.

You can learn about it from this post: [JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Please note that not all browsers might not call this with the change in toolbars.