# Resize javascript window

Tags: javascript, height, window-resize

How would I apply a resize event to this code, so it gets the new height of window if its changed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#page").height($(window).height()); 
});
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Javascript window resize event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)?

Comment: @Nightfirecat: not really. The other one is more about the event per se... this one is just related to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {

    $(window).resize(function(){
        $("#page").height($(this).height());
    }).resize();

});
```

As you may see I've also shortened the `$(document).ready(function(){})` by simply doing the `$(function(){})`.

Comment: Thanks champ, this was the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() { 
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#page").height($(window).height()); 
  });
});
```

Should work fine.

**OR [better formatting]**

```
function resizePage()
{
      $(function() {
            $("#page").height($(window).height()); 
      });
}

$(window).resize(function() { resizePage(); });
```

Comment: Yes, to make sure the code will only run on dom ready. incase user resizes window while loading. [is this problematic?]

Comment: Why not contain it within the DOM Ready event handler then? So it will always run when DOM is already ready? It's not problematic, but it seems strange, unreadable and checks DOM ready every time a window resize fires instead of binding the event on DOM ready and just executing the resize afterwards on every resize (without any additional checks).

Comment: Thanks bro, will implement it like you said in future coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#page").click(function () {  
  showHeight("window", $(window).height());  
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/height/

Make sure its at the bottom of the page.