# Display live width and height values on changing window resize

Tags: javascript, resize

In html head:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
    if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
        myWidth = window.innerWidth; myHeight = window.innerHeight;
    } else if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth ||document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
        myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else if( document.body && ( document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight ) ) {
        myWidth = document.body.clientWidth; myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
    }
</script>
```

In html body:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<p>' + myWidth + 'x' + myHeight + '</p>');
</script>
```

It works good. The question is: how can I have it to display the width/height values while resizing the browser? Like here http://quirktools.com/screenfly/ at bottom left corner.

Many thanks!

Comment: does this past stackoverflow question help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Comment: I found the code above on the web. I'm totally a beginner. If anyone can write the entire code (wrap up with my code above) that would be great. thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Bind to `window.onresize`.  Don't use `document.write()`.  Put the `<p>` in your HTML and give it an id.  Then just set the innerHTML of the element directly:

```
window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
window.onload = displayWindowSize;
function displayWindowSize() {
    // your size calculation code here
    document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML = myWidth + "x" + myHeight;
};
```

Comment: It works well on resizing the window, thanks a lot. How can I also display it for first time open the page or after a reload?

Answer (score 28):

I like gilly3's solution, but it would be useful to have the full code (for those in a hurry!)

```
<script>
    window.onresize = displayWindowSize;
    window.onload = displayWindowSize;

    function displayWindowSize() {
        myWidth = window.innerWidth;
        myHeight = window.innerHeight;
        // your size calculation code here
        document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML = myWidth + "x" + myHeight;
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Or, if you're already using jquery, you can use [`.resize(handler)`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/#resize-handler) to capture the resize event and [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/#resize) without any parameters to trigger the initial event when the window is done loading.

Like this:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    // your size calculation code here
    $("#dimensions").html(myWidth);
}).resize();
```

## [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/5PFak/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>How to get width of screen when window is resizing?</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
window.onresize=function()
{
    document.body.innerHTML=window.innerWidth;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

To learn the meaning of the each line of the code - https://jaischool.com/javascript-lang/how-to-get-live-width-of-window-when-it-is-resizing.html