# make ajax constantly send data to php script and retrieve results?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

how can you be constantly sending data through an ajax request (POST) to a script, and constantly retrieving the results? Id prefer a jquery method but plain ajax is fine too.
I need to send a javascript variable with the height of the page, but obviously theres no windowReSize event, so how can it be set up so that data is constantly being posted and retrieved? Thanks, sorry for the lame question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ozair Kafray stated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8103454/make-ajax-constantly-send-data-to-php-script-and-retrieve-results/8103536#8103536), you'd better use the setInterval method.

By the way, [the window resize event does exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event).

Also, if you don't mind supporting new browsers only, this "constant ajax stuff" is what [WebSockets](http://websocket.org/) have been invented for.

Comment: i don't mind, but old browsers do :( thanks fir the tip though!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [setinterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) method to do anything after a certain interval.

I am not sure why you want it so, I thought that one of the following thread(s) might be helpful for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hash+change+event

Answer (score 0):

you could do this by doing a recursive call in javascript try this code:

```
<script>
         function infinite()
         {
         setTimeout('infinite()', 50000);
         //put any statement here...
         jQuery.post(<parameters>);
         }

         infinite();
</script>
```

hope this helps. :)