# JSLint complains about redefining undefined

Tags: javascript, jslint, reserved-words

[`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) is technically able to be redefined, so it is not a reserved word. As a result, I usually write code in an anonymous function that forces `undefined` to be an undefined variable, as so:

```
(function (undefined) {
    "use strict";
    var o = {
        test: "testvalue"
    };
    if (o.test === undefined) {
        // Do stuff here
    } else {
        // Do other stuff there
    }
}());
```

However, [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) mentions the following error:

```
Problem at line 1 character 15: Expected an identifier and instead saw 'undefined' (a reserved word).
```

Why does JSLint complain about `undefined` being an reserved word, when code can arbitrarily redefine the variable? I know that you can use `typeof x === "undefined"`; I just wanted to see why this method wouldn't work.

Comment: "Why does JSLint complain about undefined being an reserved word" Because it is a reserved word!

Comment: @epascarello - can you please give a link to a JavaScript/ECMAScript reference that lists reserved words? I don't think `undefined` is on the list, and certainly the code above works. You can also just say `undefined = "not undefined any more"` and it will work.

Comment: @nnnnnn @epascarello According to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words), `undefined` is not a reserved word.

Comment: This code is not actually redefining `undefined` at all, it is only passing undefined as a parameter to a closure. You probably want `var undefined='something else';` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your method *does* work. Just because JSLint doesn't like it doesn't make it a cardinal sin.

Try [JSHint](http://jshint.com) instead (for more sanity).

Comment: JSHint also complains about the same thing (as of today, at least)

Answer (score 17):

'undefined' was declared an immutable property of the global object in [ECMA-262 Edition 5 Section 15.1.1.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262%205th%20edition%20December%202009.pdf), published in December 2009.

By using 'undefined' as a parameter name in a function, you are attempting to mutate it with whatever is passed to the function.  So technically, the error lies with browsers being slow to adopt the standard, and JSLint is correct.

Comment: According to that doc: The value of  undefined is  undefined (see 8.1). This property has  the attributes { [[Writable]]:  false, 
[[Enumerable]]: false, [[Configurable]]: false }. This answer deserves more up votes!

Comment: You aren't mutating anything, you are adding a scope on top that has a separate variable named `undefined` (which is also un-defined).

Comment: Yep, being a global attribute and not a keyword, you can overwrite it without problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
(function() { var undefined = 'foo'; console.log(undefined, typeof undefined); })();
```

According to MDN, it's actually not a reserved word in JavaScript and could be redefined.

Answer (score -3):

`undefined` is a reserved word. It's like trying to name a variable `false` or `true`. Your value you are passing into your function:

`function(undefined) {...}`

needs to be named something else, like

`function(myVariable) {...}`

**UPDATE**

Looks like it might not be actually reserved as [I originally read](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm) but perhaps it's just a term that JSLint thinks should be reserved...

Comment: Can you please provide a reference for JavaScript reserved words? `undefined` isn't reserved, and the code in the question works (whether JSLint likes it or not).

Comment: Well there are a lot of "Javascript reserved words" pages online, most of them are not the same but I did find this one: http://www.javascripter.net/faq/reserved.htm Interesting that the code works anyways. Maybe it's just a 'suggested' reserved word according to JSLint.