# How to get live browser's screen resolution

Tags: javascript, dom

I want to get live screen resolution of web browser as user RESTORE DOWN OR MAXIMIZE without refreshing the page.

Comment: Are you using java script on client side? More specifically jQuery?

Comment: Does [this](http://andylangton.co.uk/articles/javascript/browser-screen-resolution/) solution work for you?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Comment: how many monitors are you using?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are you using jQuery? If yes, then the code below should work

```
$(window).resize(function(){
 var windowWidth = $(window).width();
 var windowHeight = $(window).height();
 // windowWidth & windowHeight are automatically updated when the browser size is modified
});
```

Answer (score 13):

Not entirely sure what you're after, but here are some suggestions.

`window.screen` contains the current OS resolution. That is accessible via `screen.height` and `screen.width`. Two other interesting values might be `availHeight` and `availWidth` (not 100% sure about the cross-browser availabilty there)

If you need to know the current browser-dimensions, that is stored on the `window` object itself. `window.innerHeight`, `window.outerHeight`, `window.innerWidth` and `window.outerWidth` are the values of interest there. The *inner* prefixed values do reflect the working(client) area of the browser, whereas the *outer* prefixes contain the whole browser window area.