# EVENT : user change size of browser

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

I want to get an event which is triggered when a user change the size of the actual window.

Any idea to do this ?

Comment: just becomes a race with questions like this

Comment: Downvote since a google search turns this up very easily. Google: "jquery window resize event".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  //Your code
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
 // Do what you want
}
```

In jquery

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     // Do what you want
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `resize` event: http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

you can use window object, `resize` event:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    alert("you've resized the window");
});
```

The resize event is sent to the window element when the size of the browser window changes