# How to get height and width after window resize

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a scorm module which launches in a new window with resizable = 1 in window.open in my js file:

```
function OpenScormModuleWindow(scormModuleId, scormModuleUrl, title, width, height) 
{
  _scormModuleId = scormModuleId;
  InitializeUserScormModule();
  scormModuleWindow = window.open(scormModuleUrl, "title", "width=" + width + ", height=" + height + ", resizable = 1");
  scormModuleWindow.focus();
}
```

in my view I have:

```
  var myWidth = 0, myHeight = 0;
  if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number')
  {
      myWidth = window.innerWidth;
      myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  }
  else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight))
  {
      myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth; myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  }
  else if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight))
  {
      myWidth = document.body.clientWidth; myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
  }
```

I get height and width but is not correct

the user can now resize, when the window is the correct size, how can I get the height and width please?

I need to get these values so I can save it, next time the window opens it is the correct size.

thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use an event listener which listens on resize, then you can reset your values:

```
window.addEventListener('resize', setWindowSize);

function setWindowSize() {
  if (typeof (window.innerWidth) == 'number') {
    myWidth = window.innerWidth;
    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } else {
    if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
      myWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
      myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    } else {
      if (document.body && (document.body.clientWidth || document.body.clientHeight)) {
        myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
        myHeight = document.body.clientHeight;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you need a cross browser solution use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) (`$.on('resize', func)`) or see [JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Comment: Do you need to call an anonymous function to call setWindowSize? Could you not write "window.addEventListener('resize', setWindowSize);" ?

Answer (score 3):

Hope This Example Will Help You...

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Window Size : height and width</title>
</head>
<!-- Resize the window (here output panel) and see the result !-->
<body onload="getSize()" onresize="getSize()">
<div id="wh"> 
<!-- Place height and width size here! --> 
</div>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
function getSize()
{
var w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
var h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

// put the result into a h1 tag
 document.getElementById('wh').innerHTML = "<h1>Width: " + w + " Height: " + h + "</h1>";
}
```

Or You Can Also Use Jquery Code For Resize:

```
var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function() {

var height = $(window).height();
var width = $(window).width();
console.log("height"+height);
console.log("width"+width);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way as far as I can see;

```
function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight || document.body.clientHeight;

    WIDTH = canvas.width;
    HEIGHT = canvas.height;
}
```