# Auto height of element

Tags: html, css

I have 4 main sections on my website. Each one of them has width and height set to 100% using

```
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
```

The problem is in the 3rd section where there is a responsive table which is obviously changing its height. As long as it changes its height, half of the content isn't visible because it's covered by the 4th section. I tried to use

```
overflow:auto
```

which didn't work. Is there any way to make contents height 100% yet let it auto adjust its height afterwards?

I even tried to use

```
height:auto
```

but the result was that the 3rd section disappeared completely.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Is there any way to make contents height 100% yet let it auto adjust its height afterwards".  It's not clear what behavior you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: what i am trying to acomplis , to my div change automaticly its height when the content inside its too big for it , but whenever i set height:auto to it, it completly dissapear.

Comment: Height 100% should autoscale... you should post a jsfiddle, the issue you are seeing is really unclear from reading this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/tfxss1sL/ here , copied it to jsfiddle. as you can see you cant see the whole table.

Comment: You have a lot of css issues here; the issues you have are being caused by your relative positioning.  In general, the behavior you want is the default browser behavior and you are breaking it.  Check out some of the changes I have made here: https://jsfiddle.net/tfxss1sL/3/

Comment: well , your code just broke the structure (drop downs) , i removed position:relative but it still does what it shouldnt.Seems like the last section is still on the same place after the tables container adjusts its height

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the divs to:

```
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;
```

This will ensure that the elements don't become less than 100% height and width, but also allow for expansion.

Answer (score -2):

You have to set at a pixel height on at least one like `style="width: 1200px;"`

If you want to dynamicaly adjust the size of the website, try it using a javascript function.

[How to get height and width after window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596299/how-to-get-height-and-width-after-window-resize)

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onresize.asp

Hope this helps.

PS: I'm also a noob. If I'm wrong, please correct me.

Edit:
Did you tried it with a Javascript function, who is triggered by the window.resizeEvent? (resizeEvent is added to the body like `<body onresize="resize()"></body>`

I just got an example with jquery but this would look like:

```
<script>
   function resize() {
       $("#div_container_to_resize").css("height:", (window.innerHeight) + "px");
   }
</script>
```

A pure javascript solution would look like:

```
<script>
   window.addEventListener('resize', resize); 
   function resize() {
       document.getElementById("div_container_to_resize").setAttribute("height:", window.innerHeight + "px");
   }
</script>
```

For more informations and details look at the posted links.

Comment: these are two different links!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12596299/how-to-get-height-and-width-after-window-resize

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.