# javascript How to get dynamically height (when i resize browser)

Tags: javascript, css, height

I'm trying to get `height` from adjustable `div` because I'd like to add overflow style into `css` when height value will be greater than a set value. When you resize window height of this the div change. I'll explain this with some pictures:

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img801/2113/somethingo.png]

[image: http://imageshack.us/a/img7/7503/blebvle.png]

The main problem is how to get it dynamically? I mean,when you resize your own window etc.?

Comment: have you tryied a porcentual height and min-height? Can you use jquery?

Comment: Take a look at here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Answer (score 3):

In case you are able to use jQuery, I would suggest using the window.onresize method and compute the height of the div.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $(window).on("resize", function()
   {
        $("#myDiv").text("My height is " + $("#myDiv").height());
   });                                                           
});​
```

Take a look at this fiddle I created for you: http://jsfiddle.net/9ftGe/

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for monitoring the browser variables...

```
window.innerHeight

window.innerWidth
```

Whenever you check/call these variables you should get the exact window inner size and take it from there.

NB: These variables (constants to us) are case sensitive.