# nvd3 resize lineplusbarchart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, nvd3.js

I am using the [lineplusbarchart](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/examples/linePlusBarChart.html) from the nvd3 framework and I see that the chart is redrawn when the window is resized only on the horizontal axis. Vertically the height remains static, even when stretched or compressed, as you can see [here](http://nvd3.org/examples/linePlusBar.html). This leads me to believe that the only way to change the height is to initialize it each time like so:

```
<nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart data="data"
      showXAxis="true" showYAxis="true"
      margin="{left:75,top:20,bottom:50,right:75}"                                                                                  
      height="300"                            
</nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart>
```

My application uses the [ui-layout splitter](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-layout/) which allows me to expand or compress the chart as I see fit. However, on compressing vertically there is a scroll bar that gets inserted, which is not the behavior I'm looking for. There is no event in the documentation that fires on resize, so I can't pass this new height parameter to nvd3 for it to resize and redraw itself with the new dimensions. I also see a `chart.update` method in the nvd3 docs, but I'm not sure how it could work in this case.

How do I solve this problem? If I need to explain myself better, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I have finally figured this out. When you are using a directive like `nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart` in AngularJS, you need to watch for changes in height, because the angular-nvd3-directive does **not** do this automatically, at least for the height parameter.

This little piece of code in the `nvd3LinePlusBarChart` directive did it for me:

```
 scope.$watch('height',function(height) {
          if (height) {
            if (scope.chart) {
              return scope.d3Call(scope.data, scope.chart);
            } 
          }
 });
```

That's it! And in my own directive, I just update the height on event call like so:

```
 scope.$on('someEvent', function() {
    scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.height = height;
    })
  });    
}
```

Hope this helps everyone else who is struggling!

Answer (score 3):

You will have to calculate the heights dynamically based on the window resize, [here is an example on SO to get the window height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13334873/javascript-how-to-get-dynamically-height-when-i-resize-browser?answertab=active#tab-top) and pass the height value to the chart during resizing.

Here's the changes you might need :

```
nv.utils.windowResize(function() {
    chart.height(yourNewHeight);
    chart.update();
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I had seen this code elsewhere, however I was wondering what would the variable `chart` be if the code for the graph was something like `<nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart data="data" showXAxis="true" ....></nvd3-line-plus-bar-chart>`

Comment: I also found your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16474988/how-to-set-height-and-width-of-nvd3-chart really helpful! But I'm still struggling with how to access the `chart` object in my case :/

Comment: Really sorry but I am not quite sure how it works with `Angularjs` , I've added tag JavaScritpt for more support on the forum. Try to get your code onto [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can have a look at your entire code and help you out.