# Keep div centered while page width grows/shrinks

Tags: jquery, html, center

I have a floating left div so that it wraps the content.  I would like to center this div.  Unfortunately, since I do not know the exact width of this div, I cannot use `margin: 0 auto;`.  So, I decided to use jQuery to center the div.  I was able to do this correctly by using `.outerWidth()`.  The issue is, I would like the div to remain centered when the page grows/shrinks.  I thought setting the `margin-left` to a percentage would accomplish this, but it does not.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can call the centering function on window.resize

Comment: what about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event. This way you can create a function to calculate the placement. Just Call your function with the initial opening and the way which is described in the linked thread.

Comment: Post some code that you have tried and also the html markup..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the exact width of a div to center it. You can see it working here jsfiddle.net/GkGBT

CSS

```
body{
    text-align:center;
 }
.centerdiv{
   background:blue;  
   display:inline-block;
   margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;
   text-align:left;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div class="centerdiv"></div>
```

Comment: *"Unfortunately, since I do not know the exact width of this div, I cannot use margin: 0 auto;"* and with no width set it won't work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GkGBT/ Works with display:inline-block. Am I missing a part of the question?

Comment: changed the -1 to +1 nice hack :)

Comment: It's not the `.centerdiv` but the `body` text-align who does the job here. Not sure if that's suitable for OP, but the solution works, so removed the -1 :)

Comment: Thank you.  It wasn't working for me for a while, but that was because float: left (which I was using to force the div to wrap the content) was preventing it from working.  I did not realize that display: inline-block also wraps.