# Updating a variable without page refresh (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, variables, width, auto-update

Okay, I'm pretty new to the JavaScript stuff, and I would like some help.

The variable that needs to be auto-refreshed:

```
var width = document.body.clientWidth;
```

So basically, I want to do different stuff depending on the width of the document. But how do I auto-update the value of *width*? Please JavaScript only, since I don't really get jQuery yet.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: That is a common problem people face. Usually it is best to go about solving your problem in a way which does not require monitoring the clientWidth.

Comment: Can be answered by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Comment: Resize will not handle if content makes the width larger.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript is event-based so any code that gets executed is the result of an event. There are many events such as `mousemove` or `click`.

You need to figure out which events you want to listen to. Probably something related to the width of the body changing, like more data being loaded, or some animation.