# Why would the div with this flot chart not resize correctly when changing using $route (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

If I click out of the main screen,then return I see the graph doesn't resize correctly.

The HTML is simply (Some of the styling is for debugging/testing):

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-show="graphType !== 'Mood Sentiment'" style="width:100%; max-width:100%;">
      <flot id="placeholder" dataset="dataset" options="options" height="300px" style="width:100%; max-width:100%;"
            ng-disabled="graphLoading" ng-class="{disabled:graphLoading} "></flot>
    </div>
```

What its doing:

[image: Incorrect sizing of flot chart.]

What I want it to be doing:

[image: Correct sizing]

Comment: Are you including the flot resize plugin?

Comment: Nope, should I be? :)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used flot but a search looking for resize issues with flot in angular found this, one of the comments suggested the flot-resize plugin solved their issues using it with angular.

[How to make flot responsive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17242853/how-to-make-flot-responsive)

I'd suggest trying to include the flot resize js in your app and see if that fixes it.

```
<script src="../../jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="../../jquery.flot.resize.js"></script>
```

See: http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/resize/