# Loading JS flot external resources using JSFiddle

Tags: resources, external, flot, jsfiddle

I'm trying to create a JSFiddle loading external resources (Flot).  However, when I add my external resource:

```
http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js
```

I get this alert error in JSFiddle

```
You're loading resources over HTTP not HTTPS, your fiddle will not work. Do you wish to continue?
```

However, the https version of flot,

```
https://www.flotcharts.org/flot/jquery.flot.js
```

has security warnings associated with it *(in Chrome, the error is listed as "Your connection is not private")*.  What is the proper way to extenrally load flot into a JSFiddle?

Comment: Can you link to your fiddle so someone can take a look? I've found lots of other examples that work just going through the `flot` tag.

Comment: Do you have one of those examples handy?

Comment: Here's one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17242853/1288  I just searched for `[flot] fiddle` to find questions about Flot that include a fiddle.

Comment: Hey loading hte external resource from the link you sent -- http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/jquery.flot.js, results in teh same error warning me that my JSFiddle will not work.  Indeed, the FIddle does not work -- https://jsfiddle.net/edc8jd31/ .  JSFiddle needs https resources, not http, right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you're creating a fiddle, JSFiddle requests HTTPS content but it does not need it.

Create your fiddle using https://jsfiddle.net (Click ok on the warnings when adding your http:// external resources) and click save.

Once you click save, you'll be redirected to your JSFiddle saved URL. On this URL, just change `https://` to `http://` and it will work.

Example here http://jsfiddle.net/kL1wuh66/1/