# Can I catch element's resize event?

Tags: javascript, resize, dom-events

I know I can let one element resize through css3 `resize` property:

```
resize: both;
overflow: auto
```

but can I catch the resize event? like:

```
element.addEventListener('resize', fn, false);
```

I try this, but it doesn't work, is there other way to do this kind of job?

Answer (score 1):

As per this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3150139/183181), you may try:

```
var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || elem == undefined) return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    } else {
        elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
    }
};
```

Called:

```
addEvent(element, 'resize', fn);    // you may want to try 'onresize'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Jquery `.resize( handler(eventObject) )`
executed on window resize:

```
 $(window).resize(function() {
     $('#log').append('<div>Handler for .resize() called.</div>');
 });
```