# How to increase Side-bar Height dynamically?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have created a html page that contains header, sidebar and in between there is a blank page which contains products..It works fine with limited products but after adding many products the page size increase but sidebar height remains same, and half of the page has side bar and half does't have any..Kindly guide me how to stretch the sidebar to the page length.

If i increase Height from here it gives sets the sidebar height, but i can give it a fix value because there can be any number of products in a page.

```
element.style {
    height: 843px;
}
aside#sidebar {
    background: url("../images/sidebar.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #E0E0E3;
    float: left;
    margin-top: -4px;
    min-height: 500px;
    width: 23%;
}
html, div, map, dt, isindex, form, header, aside, section, section, article, footer {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Try giving sidebar and the products container, `display: table-cell`.

Comment: why not just do a resize function in javascript? .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event ---- https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: "header, sidebar and in between there is a blank page which contains products"

`in between` sidebar and header? did you mean aside the side bar..?
and by `blank page` did you mean a `<div>`?

Answer (score 2):

apply `position:relative` to your page having products, and absolutely position the sidebar inside it by applying

```
aside#sidebar {
 position:absolute;
 background: url("../images/sidebar.png") repeat scroll 0 0 #E0E0E3;
 top: 0;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 width: 23%;
}
```

apllying `top:0;` and `bottom:0` will cause the element to always stretch to the height of it's container.
Also apply `padding` for the container equal to the sidebar so that it's contents won't be hidden.

Something like this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/fqghA/)

Answer (score 1):

make your sidebar css like .sidebar{width:100%; float:left;}it will get the parent width .sidebar:after{clear:left} and remove the height which you mentioned like  height: 843px;
Hop this will help you

Answer (score 1):

One way that you can do this is to measure the scrollHeight of the products div and set the min-height of the sidebar accordingly.

Do this whenever your products div's height changes:

```
$(".sidebar").css("min-height", document.getElementById("content").scrollHeight);
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CabCb/)

---

You could also just set it to the height of the element:

```
$(".sidebar").css("min-height", $(".content").height());
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CabCb/1/)