# How to refresh the page when window width less than 767px

Tags: jquery, resize

How to refresh the page once when after resized window to less than 767px ?

I tried many examples, but it does not working well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($(window).width() < 767) {   

             location.reload();  // refresh page 

    }
    else {  

            // width more than 768px for PC  

    }
});
```

Please help~

Comment: `window.location.reload()` maybe? But wouldn't that give an infinite loop of reloads? In what browser are you testing?

Comment: I'd link to this anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on('resize',function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {   
      location.reload();  // refresh page 
    }
    else {  
      // width more than 768px for PC  
    }
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if dont want to hit the reload to early, you could delay like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on("resize", function() {
        var tm;
        clearTimeout(tm);
        tm = setTimeout(function() {
            if ($(window).width() < 767) {
                location.reload();  // refresh page 
            }
            else {
                // width more than 768px for PC  
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```