# Icon And texts stay the same size on mobile focus in

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am developing a widget for mobile web - that contains several elements, like images icons and texts.

I am looking for a way to assure all stay in the same size when screen is in focus.

is there a way to tell have 20px icon have the same relative size on every zoom in?

Answer (score 0):

You could use window.onresize, recalculate the target elements dimensions when the window dimensions change
[JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Comment: But what do I Calcualte? the screen width? how can I know how to calc?

Comment: by the way- I am not getting this event on android zoom in