# Adjust Width in CSS on the fly based on a master dynamic width

Tags: html, css, dynamic, width, fixed

I've got an interesting little problem here I'm trying to adjust the cells of my site based on the dynamic size of the window and while I can easily enough set the master cell to scale the interior cells won't follow it if I simple set them at 100 or similar.

Here's my container

```
#container {
  background-color: #063;
  width: 980px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  margin-left: auto;
  border-top-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-left-width: 1px;
  border-top-style: solid;
  border-right-style: solid;
  border-left-style: solid;
  border-top-color: #F60100;
  border-right-color: #F60100;
  border-bottom-color: #000000;
  border-left-color: #F60100;
  /* [disabled]opacity: .75; */
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

And that works fine but here's where it gets tricky I have a set of slices that serve as sort of book spines that frame the content cell, they are a set size with the body content filling the remainder of the space but so far I've had to set the container and body blocks with set numbers as simple percents won't work

```
#Option1, #Option2, #Option3, #Option4, #Option5 {
  width: 73px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#Option3 {
  width: 70px;
}

#Option4 {
  width: 90px;
}

#Option5 {
  width: 72px;
}
```

These are the static spines so they never change, at least not at the moment as height is a static value in the future id like these to scale for the display but first I need to get just the horizontal scaling working

```
#Option1Div, #Option2Div, #Option3Div, #Option4Div, #Option5Div {
  width: 594px;
  float: left;
  height: 592px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .9;
  color: #FFF;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

And this is the body content that is hard coded to the container - the spine div sizes I'd like to make this scale with the container

And a sample of my HTML as requested, I use Javascript to change the content box widths from full to 0 which creates a effect of the shelf opening up to reveal the text but even with the default first frame open it it tries to full the full width and doesn't take into account the spines

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">HEADER PICS</div>
  <div id="content">
    <div id="subsection1">LINKS SET 1</div>
    <div id="subsection2">LINKS SET 2</div>

    <div id="Option1"><img src="assets/Black_Spine.png" name="Option1" height="600" class="options" /></div><div id="Option1Div" class="option-divs">
       ContentBox1
    </div>
    <div id="Option2"><img src="assets/Blue_Spine.png" name="Option2" height="600" class="options" /></div><div id="Option2Div" class="option-divs">
       ContentBox2
    </div>
    <div id="Option3"><img src="assets/Pink_Spine.png" name="Option3" height="600" class="options" /></div><div id="Option3Div" class="option-divs">
        ContentBox3
    </div>
    <div id="Option4"><img src="assets/Red_Spine.png" name="Option4" height="600" class="options" /></div><div id="Option4Div" class="option-divs">
         ContentBox4
    </div>
    <div id="Option5"><img src="assets/Yellow_Spine.png" name="Option5" height="600" class="options" /></div><div id="Option5Div" class="option-divs">
        ContentBox5
    </div>
    <div class="breaker"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">
    FOOTER LINKS 
      </div>
  </div>
```

Alright so I think I have this figured out, I was able to use jQuery to fetch the width, tweak it as need be and pass it into the CSS. The main containers will resize as needed while resizing and on first load the content cell will grow to fit the size of the window space however I can't get the content cells to fill to fit on resize. Since the user could be in one of the secondary cells I thought it best to do a if check to see if the content cell already had a width higher then 0, if it did just adjust it to match the new values but it doesn't seem to want to work

```
$(window).resize(function () {
var pageWidth = $(window).width();
    pageWidth = pageWidth-90;
var contentWidth = pageWidth-$( '#Option1' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option2' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option3' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option4' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option5' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-10;
$('#container').css("width", pageWidth+"px");
if ($('#Option1Div').css('width').replace(/[^-d.]/g, '') > 0){
    $('#Option1Div').css("width", contentWidth+"px");
} else if ($('#Option2Div').css('width').replace(/[^-d.]/g, '') > 0){
    $('#Option2Div').css("width", contentWidth+"px");
} else if ($('#Option3Div').css('width').replace(/[^-d.]/g, '') > 0){
    $('#Option3Div').css("width", contentWidth+"px");
} else if ($('#Option4Div').css('width').replace(/[^-d.]/g, '') > 0){
    $('#Option4Div').css("width", contentWidth+"px");
} else if ($('#Option5Div').css('width').replace(/[^-d.]/g, '') > 0){
    $('#Option5Div').css("width", contentWidth+"px");
};
```

for reference here is the page load which works fine so its just the if else block

```
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();
    pageWidth = pageWidth-90;
    var contentWidth = pageWidth-$( '#Option1' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option2' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option3' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option4' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-$( '#Option5' ).width();
    contentWidth = contentWidth-10;
$('#container').css("width", pageWidth+"px");
$('#Option1Div').css("width", contentWidth+"px");
$('#Option2Div, #Option3Div, #Option4Div, #Option5Div').css("width", "0px");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just make them
    width:100%

or whatever percent you needed them to be? This is essentially what bootstrap and foundation do for fluid grids. You have rows and columns and everything is based on a percentage of its parent container. I'd give that a shot, and I think you'll be happy with the result. For example if you had:

```
<div id="parentContainer">
  <div id="childContainer">

  </div>
</div>
```

Then your css would look something like this:

```
#parentContainer {
  width:auto;
  height:auto;
}

#childContainer {
  width:100%;
}
```

Given this, childContainer will always reflect the size of parentContainer. So if you dynamically change parent, child is set to 100% of whatever parent is set to. You can set this to whatever % value you need. You can do the same thing if you need to dynamically adjust heights.

For the above example I made height and width auto, but it can be whatever value you set to it. Here's a link to the Foundation Grid I mentioned: http://foundation.zurb.com/grid.html
Here's a link to the Bootstrap Grid I mentioned: http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Yeah that was the first thing i tried but it doesnt seem to like my spines and breaks the design http://www.tokusatsuseries.com/

Comment: @NekoLLX can you post a simple version of your html structure so I can mock something up?

Comment: This is a simple example, see if this helps you any? It's using Bootstrap 3: http://jsfiddle.net/rt0h8j6o/

Comment: near as i can tell you just added a 3rd div around each block but I'm not understanding how that solves the issue as messing with the window size seems to alter the width of all the cells equally which is the exact problem i'm trying to avoid. of the 10 cells that make the content row 5 are static and never change height or width, 4 default to 0 withthe last intending to fill the remaining space and i use java script to set which one has the remaining width when you click the spines. Maybe I'm not explaining it well, the current site is linked in my first comment

Comment: Oh, so let me see if I understand. The one that defaults to open with the content is supposed to take up the remainder of the space right? So each time you click a binding the content that appears will take up the remainder of the space, correct?

Comment: Based on your configuration on tokusatsuseries.com I think your best bet would honestly be media queries for the option-divs. This is the easiest answer without changing your whole layout. So you would basically just figure out for what screen resolutions the percentage becomes too much, and then write a media query to fix it. Here's a link to media query syntax: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/   so in the query you'll see in that site, you'd just change the width percentage depending on how large you need it. Hopefully this solves some of your problems. I used dev tools to test %s.

Comment: honestly if there was just a way to fetch the size of the screen on load and resize i could use use Java to set the size of the css with attribute but i can't seem to find how to do that. I looked in media queery as well as that seemed on the right track (thanks for the link btw) but i must be blind as i cant seem to find the actual querry

Comment: @media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {} is an example, but you'd need to check the resolutions. If you use chrome you could download this extension (I use it and like it very much): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/window-resizer/kkelicaakdanhinjdeammmilcgefonfh  ... For the media query provided, inside the curly braces you'd just call the id or classes style you want to change just like normal: .myClass { width:50% } and then figure out "oh 50% is too big when i hit this resolution" and then write another media query. Could just be pixels too.

Comment: actually i fiound a solution, well 90% of a solution, sincei use jquerry i was able to use it as a pretty standard javascript function to fetch the width then able to store that into 2 variables it works for onload but i cant quite get it to do the same when the window resizes or when you check one of the other areas of the site which use different sized spines but as long as your in the year one section and don't rezise it works like a charm!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3150139/1290883 lol hopefully all this helped you.

Comment: oh it was majorly helpful, even if not in the most obvious way it started me thinking in other route now i just need to get the jquerry to behave

Comment: edited the OP with the new dynamic code (including the buggy part for content cell on reload)