# jQuery - execute scripts based on screen size while resizing the window without refrehing?

Tags: jquery, html, css

If someone can help me please?

I have coded a responsive layout, in big screen is one type of menu, in small another.
here is the jquery code:

```
if($(window).width() < 480){
        $('.menu_items').fadeOut(0);
        $('.menu-bar').click(function(){ 
            $('menu_items').fadeToggle(500 , "swing");
            });
        $('.menu_item').click(function() {
            $('menu-bar');
            });

    } else {

    $('.menu_items').fadeOut(0);
        $('.menu-bar').hover(function(){
            $(this).children().fadeIn(100, "swing");
            },function(){
                $(this).children().fadeOut(400, "swing");
                }).triger('mouseleave');
            };
```

this work fine!
In screen size 480x320 resolution and below  is active the first one function, resolution bigger then 480px is active the second one.

Here is the problem:
when I resize the window beyond the braking point (480px) there is still active the first function when I've load the html.

I must reload the page to make the the right function active.

Comment: check the size inside the click handlers and react accordingly

Comment: charlietfl, same problem
The browser won't refresh the script, 
 $( window).resize(function() { ...
this one won't do anything before I resize by one pixel the window also I must manually refresh the browser.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried wrapping it in the jQuery resize function?

https://api.jquery.com/resize/

Answer (score 0):

Use window.resize:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if($(window).width() < 480){
    $('.menu_items').fadeOut(0);
    $('.menu-bar').click(function(){ 
        $('menu_items').fadeToggle(500 , "swing");
        });
    $('.menu_item').click(function() {
        $('menu-bar');
        });

} else {

$('.menu_items').fadeOut(0);
    $('.menu-bar').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().fadeIn(100, "swing");
        },function(){
            $(this).children().fadeOut(400, "swing");
            }).triger('mouseleave');
        };
};
```

[JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has a function .resize that is called whenever element is rezised. You should be able to use it as follows:

```
$( window).resize(function() {
    if(this.width() < 480){
      $('.menu_items').fadeOut(0);
    $('.menu-bar').click(function(){ 
        $('menu_items').fadeToggle(500 , "swing");
        });
    $('.menu_item').click(function() {
        $('menu-bar');
        });

  } else {

    $('.menu_items').fadeOut(0);
       $('.menu-bar').hover(function(){
         $(this).children().fadeIn(100, "swing");
         },function(){
            $(this).children().fadeOut(400, "swing");
            }).triger('mouseleave');
         };"
    });
```