# Window resize event in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, resize, window-resize

I have been googling for a while and so far I found how to resize window with window resize directive but in my code I'm using `window.innerHeight` to get initial height. I can use it any time except I need an event to when it changes. [JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event) does not fire for me for some reason. Here is my code inside of the controller:

```
function adjustH() {
    var bodyElem = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var topP = window.getComputedStyle(bodyElem, null).getPropertyValue('padding-top');
    topP = topP.substring(0, topP.indexOf("px"));
    var bottomP = window.getComputedStyle(bodyElem, null).getPropertyValue('padding-bottom');
    bottomP = bottomP.substring(0, bottomP.indexOf("px"));
    vm.h = window.innerHeight - topP - bottomP - 20;
}

window.onresize = function(event) {
    adjustH();
}
```

Can anybody tell me if it is impossible to do it this way and I have to go the directive route? Or if its possible please tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are working with angularJS, did you pass $window as a dependency to you controller.

I have had similar issues with this before and it was because the depoendency was not set.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Would be helpful if you added your angularJS controller and any directives  or services you are using

Comment: Never mind, you you are right. But the only thing I dont understand is why my `window.innerHeight` worked and I didn't have to pass it to controller.

Comment: Also my canvas set to `height="{{vm.h}}"` but it only resizes when I mouse over

Comment: Post the rest of the code if you don't mind, it will help identify the issue... May have something to do with your scopes and/or event propagation

Answer (score -1):

After reading your comment which stated

> Also my canvas set to `height="{{vm.h}}"` but it only resizes when I mouse over

It seems that you need to call `$scope.$apply()` (or `$rootScope.$apply()`) in order to update the height property of the element.

If you add more code from your directive/controller, I could give you a more detailed answer.

Comment: I'll try this and let you know