# call a function when window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have progress bar on my page. It works, but if I resize window I have problem with it's `width` - it doesn't change.

html:

```
<h4 class="progress-title">Title <span class="pull-right">80%</span>/h4>
<div class="progressBar prog-bar1"><div></div></div>
```

javascript code

```
   function progress(percent, $element) {
        var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
        $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 5000).html(percent + "% ");
    }

    try {
        progress(80, $('.prog-bar1'));

    } catch(err) {

    }
```

How can I call function when window is resized?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript window resize event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a `resize` event to the `window` object:

```
$(function() {
   $(window).resize(function() {
       function progress(percent, $element) {
            var progressBarWidth = percent * $element.width() / 100;
            $element.find('div').animate({ width: progressBarWidth }, 5000).html(percent + "% ");
        }

        try {
            progress(80, $('.prog-bar1'));

        } catch(err) {

        }
   }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Triggering the resize event after you bind the handler to it will make sure that the code is run on page load.

Answer (score 1):

Use `window`[`resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) jQuery method.