# Is there any way to make the site go to another page when the browser window is resized?

Tags: javascript, html, browser, resize, window

I'm using HTML5. In my Javascript file, I have the following code in my Javascript file to redirect mobiles users to the mobile site. However, is there a way to redirect to the mobile site as well when the browser window is resized to 480px or below? I looked everywhere and couldn't find any solutions anywhere.

```
if( screen.width <= 480 ||  /webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)  )  {     
window.location = "mobile.html";

}
```

Comment: You're looking for the [`resize` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize).

Comment: This will be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/641874/4110233

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing to note is that `screen` is the size of a desktop user's monitor, so it may not change. Instead, use jQuery to figure out the width of the browser's window, not the `screen`:

```
<script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

  window.onresize = function(event) {
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
        console.log('do stuff');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used this code, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I would put my check in a function, run it initially, and assign the function to `window.resize` property:

```
function checkWinSize(){

    if( window.innerWidth <= 480 ||  /webOS|iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent)  )  {     
        window.location = "mobile.html";
    }

}

checkWinSize(); // intial check
window.onresize = checkWinSize; // check when window is resized
```

A drawback with `window.onresize` is that it's a property so it cannot have multiple functions. In case you might do other things window is resized, use `addEventListener`

```
window.addEventListener('resize', checkWinSize);
```

Comment: should be checking window width, not screen