# Making elements the same height does not work on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I make my elements in the same height, everything works good (it works on page load), but it does not work on resize. Need your help

```
function same_height() {
         $('.front-section').children(".row").each(function() { 
          var maxHeight= -1;
          $(this).find(".owl-item").each(function() {
           maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : 
            $(this).height();
          });
           $(this).find(".owl-item").each(function() {
             $(this).height(maxHeight);
         })
        });  
       }
     $(window).on('load',same_height);        

     $(window).on('resize',same_height);
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what the issue is. Could you give a clearer explanation of what you're trying to do

Comment: $(window).on('resize',same_height); this does not work

Comment: Is it calling the same_height method on resize at all?

Comment: On resize it is stay the same

Comment: Are you trying to cater for content wrapping on resize? By that time, you've set fixed height on all your elements, so it won't change. Look at other options for setting the same height across multiple elements, e.g. CSS flexbox.

Comment: elements in different place, I can not use css

Comment: FYI: You can optimize your code by `$(window).on('load resize',same_height);`.

Comment: You can achieve same height elements using css only - [have a look at flexbox](https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard)

Comment: The code looks fine to me. But I guess since it looks like you are trying to do this for owl carousel, you might need to refresh owl-carousel . Please try this $('.owl-carousel').trigger('refresh.owl.carousel'); after you adjust your height for the carousel

Comment: Can you set up a test case in either a snippet/JSFiddle so that we can see what the issue is? All answers are random shots in the dark without having any information about what is actually happening. The problem is probably not with the code that you've posted, but what you're trying to achieve and how.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping `$(function() { ... your code ... }` around your code to run the code when the page is loaded. Also try `console.log("test")` inside `same_height()` to check if the function runs at all

Comment: like this  ?   $(function() { 
    $(window).on('load',same_height); 
     $(window).on('resize',same_height);
  });  or full code?

Comment: yes, try it. Does the function fire on page load? If so check @garroad_ran's answer down below

Comment: okay write `console.log("test")` inside your `same_height` function and check if its written in your console

Comment: It works , but only on resize start, When I begin to resize it change height and stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/done-resizing-event/) might be the cause of it. I would guess that the on('resize') method is only firing when you start to resize the screen, whereas you want it to fire when you finish resizing.

There's also some potentially very helpful answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event) thread.

Comment: No, resize event will fire with every 1px change. But, browsers optimize it with not firing it for every pixel but with speed of resize as well. So, its always better to use `window.setTimeout` for resize or scroll events.

Comment: Well, there you go! Shows what I know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function same_height() {
    $('.front-section').children(".row").each(function() {
        var maxHeight = -1;
        $(this).find(".owl-item").each(function() {
            maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight :
                $(this).height();
        });
        $(this).find(".owl-item").each(function() {
            $(this).height(maxHeight);
        })
    });
}
$(window).on('load resize', window.setTimeout(same_height, 1));
```

Comment: @Evi: In that case it definitely has some dependency with the plugin that you are using. Try reading through the plugin options and methods. Most likely you will find some `refresh` function which will do the trick.

Comment: I tried this code without owl-carousel, it is the same.  
It works , but only on resize start, When I begin to resize window it change height and stay the same.

Comment: @Evi: In that case check CSS for your `.font-section`, `.row` etc parent containers. Something else is restricting it.

Answer (score 1):

May be your problem is from the HTML structure. Because your code is works like charm :)

```
<div class="front-section">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="owl-item red">first row</div>
    <div class="owl-item green">first row</div>
    <div class="owl-item blue">first row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If the structure is okay, your script will do the following:

- set every owl-item's height to a specific value
- on a resizing event, you will query this value, what was set earlier

But what you really need:

- set every owl-item's height to a specific value
- on a resizing event, delete this height first (to set up content required auto height)

  ```
        $(this).css('height','auto')
  ```
- and NOW query the height again

See the updated JSfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/q4p79hw5/9/

Comment: It is the  same, It takes height only on resize start .  is it in different way in your browser?

Comment: Thank you for creating it online )

Comment: If I resize this Jsfiddle demo, it is resizing the boxes properly, isn't it?

Comment: No , it does not. Put long text on red div and start to resize window. It always show 150px.

Comment: Åh, now I understand your problem. Will update my answer shortly.

Comment: Viktor, thank you veeeery much ) It works) I do not understand why my code not work as good as your in example , but it is other story ) Thank you

Comment: Feel free to ask, if there are other problems ;)