# Storing Browser Window Size in Variable and Updating It on Change

Tags: javascript, variables

I'm storing window width into a variable using `const deviceWidth = window.innerWidth;`. This is great however, I would like the variable to update anytime the user resizes the window. How is this achieved?

Comment: Since it varies, don't save it as a constant. Use `var` or `let` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Comment: Unfortunately, that is very little context. Why copy the value of `innerWidth` to a const variable? Why not just read it from `window` directly when you want to observe any changes done somwhere else?
Or is it an `Observable` what you really want? Something with an `eventListener` that triggers?

Answer (score 0):

When the window changes size it triggers a 'resize' event.
[Details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event)

You need to listen out for this event and update your variable accordingly.
[Details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

I would leverage the window resize event to keep your variable updated:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Essentially, you can create a function that is ran on any window resize and then set your variable.

```js
const heightOutput = document.querySelector('#height');
const widthOutput = document.querySelector('#width');

function reportWindowSize() {
  heightOutput.textContent = window.innerHeight;
  widthOutput.textContent = window.innerWidth;
}

window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```

```html
<p>Resize the browser window to fire the <code>resize</code> event.</p>
<p>Window height: <span id="height"></span></p>
<p>Window width: <span id="width"></span></p>
```