# JS Amcharts - Responsive relocate position of legend

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

JS Amcharts - Responsive relocate position of legend

How to change the position of the legend responsivly from "right" to "bottom" when let say the screen is (gets resized) smaller than 992px?

html:

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

js:

```
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.PieChart);

chart.data = [{
  "country": "Lithuania",
  "litres": 501.9
}, {
  "country": "Czech Republic",
  "litres": 301.9
}, {
  "country": "The Netherlands",
  "litres": 50,
  "hidden": true
}];

var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
pieSeries.dataFields.hidden = "hidden";

chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.fontSize = 12;
chart.legend.position = "right";
chart.legend.markers.template.width = 12;
chart.legend.markers.template.height = 12;
```

Fiddle: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wLEomN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just [watch the window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18520448/9662601) and change the `chart.legend.position` according to the [window width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11744120/9662601):

```
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
    chart.legend.position = "bottom";
  } else {
    chart.legend.position = "right";
  }
}, true);
```

[Here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VJGRXq) I forked your code pen and added my solution.