# How to update window.matchMedia if window size changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function only works when the page gets reloaded:

```js
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
  $("html").css("background-color", "yellow");
} else {
  $("html").css("background-color", "red");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But how can I additionally update it if the window size changes?

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event) didn't help me so far. It's hard for me to find the best solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript window resize event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Comment: @0stone0 If I take the accepted solution, then it only works on resize, but not if the page gets loaded. I can try to find another way. But it would be nice to know what's the best and most efficient way.

Comment: Just bind to both.

Comment: @0stone0 And how?

Comment: Note this can be done using css media queries alone with no script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery just put it in a resize event handler and trigger the event also when page loads

```
$(window).resize(function(){    
    if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
      $("html").css("background-color", "yellow");
    } else {
      $("html").css("background-color", "red");
    }
}).resize()// trigger on page load
```

Comment: Ingenious!! <3<3<3

Answer (score 0):

You could set up the event handler using the addEventListener() method:

```
Window.addEventListener('resize', reportWindowSize);

function reportWindowSize() {
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var width = window.innerWidth;
}
```

or

```
window.onresize = reportWindowSize;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
  if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 700px)").matches) {
    $("html").css("background-color", "yellow");
  } else {
    $("html").css("background-color", "red");
  }
};

// Resize event
window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);

// First load
window.addEventListener("load", myFunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```