# Set primitive object attributes by reference

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

I want to compensate for the possibility of a user changing the window size that contains a canvas element. I had something along the lines of:

```
class RenderClass{
   constructor(){
     this.Canvas = document.getElementById("GameView").getContext("2d");
     this.CanvasWidth = this.Canvas.canvas.width;
     this.CanvasWidth = this.Canvas.canvas.height;
   }
}
```

I have a callback setup where whenever the window is resized, I do the following:

```
RenderClass.Canvas.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
RenderClass.Canvas.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

My problem is that that `RenderClass.CanvasWidth` and `RenderClass.CanvasHeight` does not equal to `RenderClass.Canvas.canvas.width` and `RenderClass.Canvas.canvas.height` when the window size has changed.

Is there a way to accomplish this without having code that explicitly makes these two values equal? I was under the impression almost everything in JavaScript is returned by reference so when I modified the actual `Canvas` object that `CanvasWidth` and `CanvasHeight` would automatically return those values?

Comment: Those assignments just copy primitives, they don't provide references into the object. `document.getElementById("GameView").getContext("2d");`  returns a context, not a canvas.  If you find yourself writing things like `RenderClass.Canvas.canvas.width`, you may want to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0):

While you have direct access to the `canvas` element you can get `width` and `height` from it directly. Just as you set them.

If you still need to keep `CanvasWidth`/`CanvasHeight` class properties and be sure they're in sync with actual canvas' dimenstions I'd propose to use getters/setters for that:

```js
class RenderClass{
   constructor(id){
     this.Canvas = document.getElementById(id).getContext("2d");
   }
   
   get canvasWidth() {
     return this.Canvas.canvas.width
   }
   set canvasWidth(width) {
     this.Canvas.canvas.width = width
   }
   
   get canvasHeight() {
     return this.Canvas.canvas.height
   }
   set canvasHeight(height) {
     this.Canvas.canvas.height = height
   }
}

const render = new RenderClass("GameView")

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  render.canvasWidth = window.innerWidth
  render.canvasHeight = window.innerHeight

  console.log(render.canvasWidth, render.canvasHeight)
})
```

```css
html, body, #GameView {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="GameView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Those assignments just copy primitives, they don't provide references into the object.

You can (and should) minimize the problem down to:

```js
const o = {foo: 42};
let {foo} = o;
foo = 600;
console.log(o); // what happened? I expected {foo: 600}...
```

Additionally, `document.getElementById("GameView").getContext("2d");` returns a canvas *context*, not a canvas. It should be named as such, `context`. It so happens you can grab the canvas from the context but it's sort of awkward and invasive: `RenderClass.Canvas.canvas.width` (yikes...).

What's the point of this class exactly? If it's responsible for rendering, it shouldn't allow getters on canvas height and width -- those are properties of the canvas member, not the renderer. If you want to wrap the canvas class, write a class `Canvas` that has these getters and setters, then offer a getter into the underlying canvas on the `Renderer` class.

The syntax for setting width would be `renderer.canvas.width = 42` rather than `renderer.setWdith = 42`.

The other option would be to completely hide the canvas as an implementation detail of a renderer. In that design, the canvas would not be exposed at all, so the height/width getters/setters would make sense. But then there'd not be a getter for the canvas exposed by the `Renderer` interface -- all interactions between the client and the underlying `Renderer#canvas` would be mediated by the `Renderer` interface.

Passing in an id to the constructor for `RenderClass` is odd. There's no reason to tie down the class to only work with a subset of HTML elements that happen to have ids. A renderer doesn't need to know about the `document`. Better is to pass in an arbitrary canvas element rather than baking `getElementById` into the constructor. Think of it like the `ReactDOM.render` call (if you're familiar with React), which lets the client specify the element. It'd be frustrating if React *forced* you to use an id and did the document traversal call under the hood -- we should be able to inject mocks into this.

As a final note, variables, including instance variables, should be named lowercase -- uppercase is for classes. CSS ids should be kebab case, `#game-view`, not PascalCase. It's poor style to name a class `FooClass` -- just `Foo`. The capital is enough to distinguish it as a class.

Playing along with the class design (right now, I don't think you need classes at all, but I assume you have bigger abstractions to build), here's a rewrite suggestion:

```js
class Canvas {
  constructor(canvas) {
    this._canvas = canvas;
    this._context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  }
  
  get width() {
    return this._canvas.width;
  }
  set width(width) {
    this._canvas.width = width;
  }
  
  get height() {
    return this._canvas.height;
  }
  set height(height) {
    this._canvas.height = height;
  }
  
  // ...
}

class Renderer {
  constructor(cavas) {
    this._canvas = canvas;
  }
  
  get canvas() {
    return this._canvas;
  }
  set canvas(canvas) {
    this._canvas = canvas;
  }
  
  // ...
}

const canvas = new Canvas(document.querySelector("#game-view"));
const renderer = new Renderer(canvas);

const handleResize = () => {
  renderer.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  renderer.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  console.log(
    renderer.canvas.width,
    renderer.canvas.height
  );
};
window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
handleResize();
```

```css
html, body, #game-view {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="game-view"></canvas>
```

Don't forget to [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43245016/6243352) your resize calls.