# How to reset display on a div after changing device size

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

This is my code and it's horizontal on desktop screen and on phone it's vertical and x button(closebtn) is only on phone displayed and closes the menu bar. How do I automatically display it again, after resizing the page to desktop size?

```js
function oty() {
  document.getElementById("tab").style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-bar" id="tab">
  <button class="closebtn" onclick="oty()">X</button>
  <button class="tablink">Home</button>
  <button class="tablink">News</button>
  <button class="tablink">Contact</button>
  <button class="tablink">About</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### RECOMMENDED: Stick to CSS `@media`

You can easily add media queries that determine a display of any given element based on viewport size, which is the foundation of *responsive design* anyways. In your case, keeping the markup as-is, the CSS could be something like...

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { // Adjust the break-point size as needed
  #tab {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

### Not recommended: listen for `resize` event and check the viewport size

While I'd strongly advise against using JavaScript for something CSS is built for, it is possible with JavaScript. Try something like following.

1. Add a `resize` event listener to window: (e.g. `window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)`)
2. Write a function that toggles your `tab` element's visibility.
3. Consider adding a throttle handler to prevent over-firing the events.

Comment: yes i see but after i did it nothing happened and from inspect element i understood it's because java script's command is rathered than css's(@media screen and (min-width: 900px)) is there any solution for this or i should change the code completely

Comment: Based on the code you shared, clicking `.closebtn` button will hide its parent div `#tab`. After that point, you have to listen for window's resize event to restore its visibility based on viewport width. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641857/javascript-window-resize-event)

Again, I'd advise against it. My recommendation is to remove `.closebtn` button element, and take advantage of CSS more to toggle `#tab` visibility. See [this tutorial](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-a-responsive-navbar-with-a-toggle-menu-using-flexbox-3438e1d08783/).