# Javascript won't properly add class to HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, width

I've written scripts before that target HTML elements and add or remove classes based on conditions before, but this current script always adds `mobile-class` no matter what the display width of my window is. The `console.log` correctly outputs `desktop` at window widths above 992px, but the class doesn't correctly change. If I manually set the top statement to equal to `desktop`, then the classes update accordingly, so it seems that my `displaySizeReader` isn't correctly assigning a value to my `displaySize` variable. Where is the break in my logic here?

```js
let displaySize = '';

function changeToMobile() {
    document.querySelector('.custom-menu-class').classList.remove('desktop-class');
    document.querySelector('.custom-menu-class').classList.add('mobile-class');
}

function changeToDesktop() {
    document.querySelector('.custom-menu-class').classList.remove('mobile-class');
    document.querySelector('.custom-menu-class').classList.add('desktop-class');
}

function displaySizeReader() {
    if (screen.width < 992) {
        let displaySize = 'mobile';
        console.log(displaySize);
    }
    else {
        let displaySize = 'desktop';
        console.log(displaySize);
    }

    function displayChanger() {
        if(displaySize == "mobile") {
            changeToMobile();
        } else if(displaySize == "desktop") {
            changeToDesktop();
        } else {
            changeToMobile();
        }
    }
    displayChanger();
}

displaySizeReader();
```

Comment: Are you expecting it change the styles automatically after your first run?

Comment: @rrkjonnapalli Yes, I would like the style to update. I know that I currently have the function set to run on page load, but I assume there's an event listener I can add to run the function again anytime the screen width is changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/641874/7339040
try to call the function after you receive an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screen object is not going to change unless you are using different displays. If you are trying to change these classes for a responsive type of scenario, the following should help you.

Make this change:

```
function displaySizeReader() {
    if (window.innerWidth < 992) {
        displaySize = 'mobile';
        console.log(displaySize);
    }
    else {
        displaySize = 'desktop';
        console.log(displaySize);
    }

    function displayChanger() {
        if(displaySize == "mobile") {
            changeToMobile();
        } else if(displaySize == "desktop") {
            changeToDesktop();
        } else {
            changeToMobile();
        }
    }
    displayChanger();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code really helped. Now I just need to add an event listener so that this function runs every time the window width is changed.

Comment: You can use window.addEventListener('resize', displaySizeReader);

Answer (score 1):

You have `let` in front of `displaySize` in your if/else statement, hence defining a new variables instead of using the one you declared in the first line.

Comment: Thanks, this was a big issue and helped resolve my code.