# How do I resize a Google Map with JavaScript after it has loaded?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

I have a 'mapwrap' div set to 400px x 400px and inside that I have a Google 'map' set to 100% x 100%. So the map loads at 400 x 400px, then with JavaScript I resize the 'mapwrap' to 100% x 100% of the screen - the google map resizes to the whole screen as I expected but tiles start disappearing before the right hand edge of the page.

Is there a simple function I can call to cause the Google map to re-adjust to the larger size 'mapwrap' div?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you're using Google Maps v2, call `checkResize()` on your map after resizing the container.  [link](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GMap2)

**UPDATE**

Google Maps JavaScript API v2 was deprecated in 2011. It is not available anymore.

Comment: Can you provide a link with this deprecation? I can't find it in the Google Maps documentation.

Answer (score 325):

for Google Maps v3, you need to trigger the resize event differently:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
```

See the documentation for the resize event (you'll need to search for the word 'resize'): http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/reference.html#event

---

**Update**

This answer has been here a long time, so a little demo might be worthwhile & although it uses jQuery, there's no real need to do so.

```js
$(function() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map-canvas")[0], mapOptions);

  // listen for the window resize event & trigger Google Maps to update too
  $(window).resize(function() {
    // (the 'map' here is the result of the created 'var map = ...' above)
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  });
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
#map-canvas {
  min-width: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 200px;
  height: 80%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&dummy=.js"></script>
Google Maps resize demo
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

**UPDATE 2018-05-22**

With a new renderer release in version 3.32 of Maps JavaScript API the resize event is no longer a part of `Map` class.

The documentation states

> When the map is resized, the map center is fixed
>
> - The full-screen control now preserves center.
> - **There is no longer any need to trigger the resize event manually.**

source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/new-renderer

`google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` doesn't have any effect starting from version 3.32

Comment: To anyone using goMap, remember that the google map object is available at $.goMap.map

Comment: See [this answer by Andrew Hedges](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969091/737393) for a way to implement:

Comment: The map wouldn't resize after calling this, until I wrapped it with a setTimeout. I found that solution [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1448) (see comment #46).

Comment: This answer should be picked considering that v2 is now deprecated. @Tyler Collier this event trigger is to notify the map that it has to repaint itself. It's possible that you are resizing a hidden container, in which case, yes, a zoom out and in would work in a timeout.

Answer (score 8):

The popular answer `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` didn't work for me alone.

Here was a trick that assured that the page had loaded and that the map had loaded as well. By setting a listener and listening for the idle state of the map you can then call the event trigger to resize.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); 
    });
});
```

This was my answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

*This is best it will do the Job done.
It will re-size your Map. 
No need to inspect element anymore to re-size your Map.
What it does it will automatically trigger re-size event .*

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function()
        {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
        });

        map_array[Next].setZoom( map.getZoom() - 1 );
    map_array[Next].setZoom( map.getZoom() + 1 );
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for guiding me and closing this issue. I found a way to fix this issue from your discussions. Yeah, Let's come to the point.
The thing is I'm Using GoogleMapHelper v3 helper in CakePHP3. When i tried to open bootstrap modal popup, I got struck with the grey box issue over the map. It's been extended for 2 days. Finally i got a fix over this.

We need to Update the GoogleMapHelper to fix the issue

Need to add the below script in setCenterMap function

```
google.maps.event.trigger({$id}, \"resize\");
```

And need the include below code in JavaScript

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce({$id}, 'idle', function(){
   setCenterMap(new google.maps.LatLng({$this->defaultLatitude}, 
   {$this->defaultLongitude}));
});
```