# JQuery FancyBox with Google Maps

Tags: jquery, html, css, drupal-6, fancybox

I am able to print the map using Drupal code in a div. I would like this map to appear inside a fancybox and to be hidden on the website. I've managed to do it (fancybox works ok) however the map is not displayed correctly - there is no navigation and only grey empty area inside Map (though google logo is there). Does anyone have an idea what could be wrong here? I guess it might be the case that ID renders only one element, so it only renders the background and the rest is ignored, but to be honest I have no idea(use class instead). Any advice appreciated. Thanks

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'overlayColor'      : '#ccffee',
    'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8
    });
});

</script>
```

Link to show the map:

```
<a id="inline" href="#mapcontainer" >
Show Map
</a>
```

Actual Div that prints the map (works perfectly when set visible)

```
<div style="display:none">
<div id="mapcontainer">
<?php print $node->content['field_maploc']['field']['items']['#children'] ?> </div></div>
```

The PHP code generates the following html:

```
<div style="width: auto; height: 400px;" id="openlayers-container-openlayers-map-auto-id-0" class="openlayers-container openlayers-container-preset-question_map"> <div style="width: auto; height: 400px;" id="openlayers-map-auto-id-0" class="openlayers-map openlayers-preset-question_map"></div> </div>
```

The current output - [image: output]

Comment: do you have an example page??

Comment: could you show what html is rendered within `<div id="mapcontainer" />
`?

Comment: @JFK please see the updated html code.

Comment: If I remove Display:none everything works perfectly, but the map is displayed on the page as well..any idea how to hide it in a different way?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something here, I was expecting to see some code from google or if the map was rendering within an iframe or so. Your html code doesn't say anything to me but nested `div` with no content. QUESTION: do you really need to print the map via Drupal code or you would rather link to the map directly via fancybox?? What I mean is if the map has to be hidden in your page (which would affect the page load) or just call it directly with fancybox?

Comment: The map is rendered via the drupal field, I dont have the actual gmap code, becuase it is rendered dynamically via third party module. That's also why it cannot be rendered via iframe. But that's not the issue - the map is rendered 100% ok, it is an issue with css/fanybox/display:none. When I remove display:none it renders OK in the fancybox, so no issue with the php code. I am sure it is something with html IDs and fancybox. But I read there is a lot of problems with inline fancybox embedding.

Comment: you are using fancybox v1.3.4, aren't you? got any link to see the issue?

Comment: @JFK Yes - 1.3.4. Do you think that v2 can solve the problem? It is running locally, but see the image.

Comment: Have you tried hiding that div using jquery on load instead of inline style?

Answer (score 5):

It seems to be an issue (bug?) when google maps is initialized in a hidden `div` (can be the same case when using tabs) since `display:none` may set its `width` and `height` to `0`.

When the inline map is visible, fancybox is able to compute its dimensions, hence it works when you remove `display:none`.

The workaround should be resizing the map once the fancybox is already opened so the map will fit into the fancybox dimensions. You can use the `onComplete` callback for that.

Other things to bear in mind:

- You may need to set `autoDimensions` either `true` or `false` depending on whether the selector `#mapcontainer` has css dimensions or not (set to `false` if not, otherwise set to `true`.) I would think it has dimensions since you can display the map inline so the initial value would be `true`.
- Since you are using inline content (fancybox v1.3.x) beware of [this bug](http://groups.google.com/group/fancybox/browse_thread/thread/fab7b6d81a173b33). The same link also shows the workaround.

So your fancybox custom script should look like:

```
 $("a#inline").fancybox({
  'hideOnContentClick': false, // so you can handle the map
  'overlayColor'      : '#ccffee',
  'overlayOpacity'    : 0.8,
  'autoDimensions': true, // the selector #mapcontainer HAS css width and height
  'onComplete': function(){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
  },
  'onCleanup': function() {
   var myContent = this.href;
   $(myContent).unwrap();
  } // fixes inline bug
 });
```

the method to resize the map might be different depending on the version of google maps API you are using

You can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2590049/1055987 for further reference.

**UPDATE**: I have added a [DEMO here](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/googleMapInline_05jun12.html)

Comment: Wow, many thanks! It didn't change anything except from close button not working now. But I checked and it seems that I am using api v2...Can you please give me the code for it, I am confused now..Thank you so muh for your help!

Comment: OK solved it! I removed display:none, put it in a wrapper with width and height equal to 0 and margin -9999px. Works perfectly. It wasn't the case with map resize - now it works with both google and yahoo maps, rather strange behaviour of display property.  Many thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: For google maps v2 check https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference#GMap2 .... it may help somebody else (checkResize() method)

Answer (score 0):

It's the `hideContentOnClick` parameter. Try setting that parameter to `false`.

Comment: it is not.. The map is not randered properly, no navigation buttons, no actual streets, just the bakground, however it works perfectly when outside fancybox.

Comment: when I remove display:none everything works but the map appears on the page as well, not only within fancybox...

Comment: maybe this will help [https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/115](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/115)